# Take a screenshot via a Python script on Linux

Tags: python, linux, screenshot

I want to take a screenshot via a python script and unobtrusively save it.

I'm only interested in the Linux solution, and should support any X based environment.

Comment: Any reason you can't use [scrot](http://linux.die.net/man/1/scrot)?

Comment: New link: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/karmic/man1/scrot.1.html (@ArtOfWarfare)

Comment: @Mark - :-/ Regrettably, Scrot doesn't come with OS X (I know, this was a Linux question. Just normally whatever applies to Linux can also apply to OS X verbatim.)

Comment: Ahh right, well it's screencapture on OS X.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

This works without having to use scrot or ImageMagick.

```
import gtk.gdk

w = gtk.gdk.get_default_root_window()
sz = w.get_size()
print "The size of the window is %d x %d" % sz
pb = gtk.gdk.Pixbuf(gtk.gdk.COLORSPACE_RGB,False,8,sz[0],sz[1])
pb = pb.get_from_drawable(w,w.get_colormap(),0,0,0,0,sz[0],sz[1])
if (pb != None):
    pb.save("screenshot.png","png")
    print "Screenshot saved to screenshot.png."
else:
    print "Unable to get the screenshot."
```

Borrowed from http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=2681009&postcount=5

Comment: This doesn't work in GUI based application using glade and quickly, can you improve this code.

Comment: When I execute this code (using linux mint 16 in virtualbox) the resulting image is completely black. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Sometimes the encoding of the colors is off. It's quite annoying. See if https://github.com/JDong820/neobot/blob/master/Linux/Robot/screen.py is any help to you; notice the call to get_rowstride.

Comment: More up-to-date version of this answer is found at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18167299/how-can-i-import-gtk-gdk-from-gi-repository

Answer (score 56):

Just for completeness:
Xlib - But it's somewhat slow when capturing the whole screen:

```
from Xlib import display, X
import Image #PIL

W,H = 200,200
dsp = display.Display()
try:
    root = dsp.screen().root
    raw = root.get_image(0, 0, W,H, X.ZPixmap, 0xffffffff)
    image = Image.fromstring("RGB", (W, H), raw.data, "raw", "BGRX")
    image.show()
finally:
    dsp.close()
```

One could try to trow some types in the bottleneck-files in PyXlib, and then compile it using Cython. That could increase the speed a bit.

---

**Edit:**
We can write the core of the function in C, and then use it in python from ctypes, here is something I hacked together:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <X11/X.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
//Compile hint: gcc -shared -O3 -lX11 -fPIC -Wl,-soname,prtscn -o prtscn.so prtscn.c

void getScreen(const int, const int, const int, const int, unsigned char *);
void getScreen(const int xx,const int yy,const int W, const int H, /*out*/ unsigned char * data) 
{
   Display *display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
   Window root = DefaultRootWindow(display);

   XImage *image = XGetImage(display,root, xx,yy, W,H, AllPlanes, ZPixmap);

   unsigned long red_mask   = image->red_mask;
   unsigned long green_mask = image->green_mask;
   unsigned long blue_mask  = image->blue_mask;
   int x, y;
   int ii = 0;
   for (y = 0; y < H; y++) {
       for (x = 0; x < W; x++) {
         unsigned long pixel = XGetPixel(image,x,y);
         unsigned char blue  = (pixel & blue_mask);
         unsigned char green = (pixel & green_mask) >> 8;
         unsigned char red   = (pixel & red_mask) >> 16;

         data[ii + 2] = blue;
         data[ii + 1] = green;
         data[ii + 0] = red;
         ii += 3;
      }
   }
   XDestroyImage(image);
   XDestroyWindow(display, root);
   XCloseDisplay(display);
}
```

And then the python-file:

```
import ctypes
import os
from PIL import Image

LibName = 'prtscn.so'
AbsLibPath = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + os.path.sep + LibName
grab = ctypes.CDLL(AbsLibPath)

def grab_screen(x1,y1,x2,y2):
    w, h = x2-x1, y2-y1
    size = w * h
    objlength = size * 3

    grab.getScreen.argtypes = []
    result = (ctypes.c_ubyte*objlength)()

    grab.getScreen(x1,y1, w, h, result)
    return Image.frombuffer('RGB', (w, h), result, 'raw', 'RGB', 0, 1)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
  im = grab_screen(0,0,1440,900)
  im.show()
```

Comment: This is worth gold, if not at least more up votes than the other answers. Solid work and a native one too! Cheers!

Comment: for those who are looking for a fast way: this approach takes ~25ms in average for a pic of size 1000 x 1000.

Comment: @JHolta, do you know a way of changing the quality of the captured image? (in order to speed up even more)

Comment: Nope. Currently it's just copying the desktop image as is, any transformation of the image will yield an overhead. So without reducing the actual quality of your desktop, you're out of luck on that idea. Anyway, the current overhead is presumably on the Python end of things, where we pre-allocate a buffer (can prob. be done in c), and the other slow part where PIL reads in this buffer, both those can be optimized, and maybe placed on the C end of things.

Comment: This works great, but I had to `#include <X11/Xutil.h>` instead of `#include <X11/Xlib.h>`. Also for compiling, I had to move `-lX11` to the end like this: `gcc -shared -O3 -Wall -fPIC -Wl,-soname,prtscn -o prtscn.so prtscn.c -lX11`.

Comment: Upon further stress testing, this leaks resources in various ways when capturing many frames in succession. You must release the X11 display, which I believe is limited to 255 clients by default. Even if you increase that limit, by not also releasing the image/window, you'll eventually run out of memory. I've submitted an edit above which addresses these problems.

Comment: This is the most fundamental answer out there, and the one with the best performance.

Comment: @Mrlenny I'm also interested in speedups. I think one option is to lower the __bit depth__ of your entire X environment, so that XGetImage (which is the main workhorse) actually returns a lower-quality image.

Comment: 0xffffffff how did you know it was 0xffffffff?

Comment: Easy to fix error: `Exception: fromstring() has been removed. Please call frombytes() instead.`

Answer (score 50):

Compile all answers in one class.
Outputs PIL image.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8
"""
screengrab.py

Created by Alex Snet on 2011-10-10.
Copyright (c) 2011 CodeTeam. All rights reserved.
"""

import sys
import os

import Image


class screengrab:
    def __init__(self):
        try:
            import gtk
        except ImportError:
            pass
        else:
            self.screen = self.getScreenByGtk

        try:
            import PyQt4
        except ImportError:
            pass
        else:
            self.screen = self.getScreenByQt

        try:
            import wx
        except ImportError:
            pass
        else:
            self.screen = self.getScreenByWx

        try:
            import ImageGrab
        except ImportError:
            pass
        else:
            self.screen = self.getScreenByPIL


    def getScreenByGtk(self):
        import gtk.gdk      
        w = gtk.gdk.get_default_root_window()
        sz = w.get_size()
        pb = gtk.gdk.Pixbuf(gtk.gdk.COLORSPACE_RGB,False,8,sz[0],sz[1])
        pb = pb.get_from_drawable(w,w.get_colormap(),0,0,0,0,sz[0],sz[1])
        if pb is None:
            return False
        else:
            width,height = pb.get_width(),pb.get_height()
            return Image.fromstring("RGB",(width,height),pb.get_pixels() )

    def getScreenByQt(self):
        from PyQt4.QtGui import QPixmap, QApplication
        from PyQt4.Qt import QBuffer, QIODevice
        import StringIO
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        buffer = QBuffer()
        buffer.open(QIODevice.ReadWrite)
        QPixmap.grabWindow(QApplication.desktop().winId()).save(buffer, 'png')
        strio = StringIO.StringIO()
        strio.write(buffer.data())
        buffer.close()
        del app
        strio.seek(0)
        return Image.open(strio)

    def getScreenByPIL(self):
        import ImageGrab
        img = ImageGrab.grab()
        return img

    def getScreenByWx(self):
        import wx
        wx.App()  # Need to create an App instance before doing anything
        screen = wx.ScreenDC()
        size = screen.GetSize()
        bmp = wx.EmptyBitmap(size[0], size[1])
        mem = wx.MemoryDC(bmp)
        mem.Blit(0, 0, size[0], size[1], screen, 0, 0)
        del mem  # Release bitmap
        #bmp.SaveFile('screenshot.png', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG)
        myWxImage = wx.ImageFromBitmap( myBitmap )
        PilImage = Image.new( 'RGB', (myWxImage.GetWidth(), myWxImage.GetHeight()) )
        PilImage.fromstring( myWxImage.GetData() )
        return PilImage

if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = screengrab()
    screen = s.screen()
    screen.show()
```

Comment: I don't know if there has been a change to wxWidgets since this post, but the `getScreenByWx` method fails with `wx._core.PyNoAppError: The wx.App object must be created first!`. Funnily enough, the code works fine if you're entering it line by line in the python shell but in a script it fails.

Comment: You should test your code! Or, not your, if you're publishing it... In `getScreenByWx` you should a) replace `myBitmap` by `bmp` and b) save `wx.App()` into a variable. In `getScreenByGtk` replace `(pb != None)` to `pb is None`. And do not use Qt so - you can't create two times `QApplication` - your app will crash on try to create it second time.

Answer (score 19):

This one works on X11, and perhaps on Windows too (someone, please check). Needs [PyQt4](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro):

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import QPixmap, QApplication
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
QPixmap.grabWindow(QApplication.desktop().winId()).save('test.png', 'png')
```

Comment: Please make note of PyQt's licensing, which is more restrictive than Python and Qt.  http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/license

Comment: It's the only solution that runs on my Linux installations "out-of-the-box". I don't know why, but I have PyQt4 everywhere, while lack of PyWX, PyGtk, ImageGrab. - Thanks :).

Comment: The code just worked (on Windows 7 x64 - Python 2.7.5; Pythonxy distrubution). Jpeg also available (e.g. ... .save('d:/test.jpg', 'jpeg'))

Answer (score 18):

I have a wrapper project ([pyscreenshot](https://github.com/ponty/pyscreenshot)) for scrot, imagemagick, pyqt, wx and pygtk.
If you have one of them, you can use it.
All solutions are included from this discussion.

Install:

```
easy_install pyscreenshot
```

Example:

```
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab

# fullscreen
im=ImageGrab.grab()
im.show()

# part of the screen
im=ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(10,10,500,500))
im.show()

# to file
ImageGrab.grab_to_file('im.png')
```

Comment: ImportError: cannot import name gtkpixbuf

Comment: it giving me this error: `pyscreenshot.tempexport.RunProgError: No protocol specified
giblib error: Can't open X display. It *is* running, yeah?" timeout_happened=False>
`

Answer (score 9):

Cross platform solution using [wxPython](http://wxpython.org):

```
import wx
wx.App()  # Need to create an App instance before doing anything
screen = wx.ScreenDC()
size = screen.GetSize()
bmp = wx.EmptyBitmap(size[0], size[1])
mem = wx.MemoryDC(bmp)
mem.Blit(0, 0, size[0], size[1], screen, 0, 0)
del mem  # Release bitmap
bmp.SaveFile('screenshot.png', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG)
```

Comment: References, with comments, explanation, and context within python code. http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/04/16/how-to-take-a-screenshot-of-your-wxpython-app-and-print-it/  or http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/04/16/how-to-take-a-screenshot-of-your-wxpython-app-and-print-it/

Answer (score 6):

```
import ImageGrab
img = ImageGrab.grab()
img.save('test.jpg','JPEG')
```

this requires Python Imaging Library

Comment: Only works on Windows:  http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/imagegrab.htm

Answer (score 4):

I couldn't take screenshot in Linux with pyscreenshot or scrot because output of `pyscreenshot` was just a black screen png image file.

but thank god there was another very easy way for taking screenshot in Linux without installing anything. just put below code in your directory and run with `python demo.py`

```
import os
os.system("gnome-screenshot --file=this_directory.png")
```

also there is many available options for `gnome-screenshot --help`

```
Application Options:
  -c, --clipboard                Send the grab directly to the clipboard
  -w, --window                   Grab a window instead of the entire screen
  -a, --area                     Grab an area of the screen instead of the entire screen
  -b, --include-border           Include the window border with the screenshot
  -B, --remove-border            Remove the window border from the screenshot
  -p, --include-pointer          Include the pointer with the screenshot
  -d, --delay=seconds            Take screenshot after specified delay [in seconds]
  -e, --border-effect=effect     Effect to add to the border (shadow, border, vintage or none)
  -i, --interactive              Interactively set options
  -f, --file=filename            Save screenshot directly to this file
  --version                      Print version information and exit
  --display=DISPLAY              X display to use
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use this

```
import os
os.system("import -window root screen_shot.png")
```

Comment: This is a good approach once u can get the image from a background program, but is good to know that if the program is focused it'll return an exception.

Comment: too bad it has already been suggested 3 years before (in 2015) by @anderstood who even included in his answer a link to the source where he got it.

Answer (score 3):

bit late but nevermind easy one is

```
import autopy
import time
time.sleep(2)
b = autopy.bitmap.capture_screen()
b.save("C:/Users/mak/Desktop/m.png")
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a python package for this [Autopy](http://www.autopy.org/)

The bitmap module can to screen grabbing (bitmap.capture_screen)
It is multiplateform (Windows, Linux, Osx).

Answer (score 2):

From [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=448160):

```
 import os
 os.system("import -window root temp.png")
```

Answer (score 2):

for ubuntu this work for me, you can take a screenshot of select window with this:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
gi.require_version('Gdk', '3.0')

from gi.repository import Gdk
from gi.repository import GdkPixbuf
import numpy as np
from Xlib.display import Display

#define the window name
window_name = 'Spotify'

#define xid of your select 'window'
def locate_window(stack,window):
    disp = Display()
    NET_WM_NAME = disp.intern_atom('_NET_WM_NAME')
    WM_NAME = disp.intern_atom('WM_NAME') 
    name= []
    for i, w in enumerate(stack):
        win_id =w.get_xid()
        window_obj = disp.create_resource_object('window', win_id)
        for atom in (NET_WM_NAME, WM_NAME):
            window_name=window_obj.get_full_property(atom, 0)
            name.append(window_name.value)
    for l in range(len(stack)):
        if(name[2*l]==window):
            return stack[l]

window = Gdk.get_default_root_window()
screen = window.get_screen()
stack = screen.get_window_stack()
myselectwindow = locate_window(stack,window_name)
img_pixbuf = Gdk.pixbuf_get_from_window(myselectwindow,*myselectwindow.get_geometry())
```

to transform pixbuf into array

```
def pixbuf_to_array(p):
    w,h,c,r=(p.get_width(), p.get_height(), p.get_n_channels(), p.get_rowstride())
    assert p.get_colorspace() == GdkPixbuf.Colorspace.RGB
    assert p.get_bits_per_sample() == 8
    if  p.get_has_alpha():
        assert c == 4
    else:
        assert c == 3
    assert r >= w * c
    a=np.frombuffer(p.get_pixels(),dtype=np.uint8)
    if a.shape[0] == w*c*h:
        return a.reshape( (h, w, c) )
    else:
        b=np.zeros((h,w*c),'uint8')
        for j in range(h):
            b[j,:]=a[r*j:r*j+w*c]
        return b.reshape( (h, w, c) )

beauty_print = pixbuf_to_array(img_pixbuf)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's an old question. I would like to answer it using new tools.

Works with python 3 (should work with python 2, but I haven't test it) and PyQt5.

Minimal working example. Copy it to the python shell and get the result.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
app = QApplication([])
screen = app.primaryScreen()
screenshot = screen.grabWindow(QApplication.desktop().winId())
screenshot.save('/tmp/screenshot.png')
```

Comment: have you got the average time for this function to complete?
just interest if worth it

Comment: @Mrlenny 300 ms (for full code), 165 ms (last three lines of code).

Answer (score -4):

Try it:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import gtk.gdk
import time
import random
import socket
import fcntl
import struct
import getpass
import os
import paramiko     

while 1:
    # generate a random time between 120 and 300 sec
    random_time = random.randrange(20,25)
    # wait between 120 and 300 seconds (or between 2 and 5 minutes) 

    print "Next picture in: %.2f minutes" % (float(random_time) / 60)

    time.sleep(random_time)
    w = gtk.gdk.get_default_root_window()   
    sz = w.get_size()
    print "The size of the window is %d x %d" % sz
    pb = gtk.gdk.Pixbuf(gtk.gdk.COLORSPACE_RGB,False,8,sz[0],sz[1])
    pb = pb.get_from_drawable(w,w.get_colormap(),0,0,0,0,sz[0],sz[1])
    ts = time.asctime( time.localtime(time.time()) )
    date = time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
    timer = time.strftime("%I:%M:%S%p")
    filename = timer
    filename += ".png"

    if (pb != None):
        username = getpass.getuser() #Get username
        newpath = r'screenshots/'+username+'/'+date #screenshot save path
        if not os.path.exists(newpath): os.makedirs(newpath)
        saveas = os.path.join(newpath,filename)
        print saveas
        pb.save(saveas,"png")
    else:
        print "Unable to get the screenshot."
```

Comment: What is this crap? Half the imports are useless, there's a `while` loop which never exits (and uses `1` instead of `True`), has `if (pb != None):` instead of just `if pb:`, has some pointless raw strings.