# Is there a Python equivalent to Java's AWT Robot class?

Tags: python, linux, automation, screenshot, awtrobot

Does anyone know of a Python class similar to [Java Robot](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html)?

Specifically I would like to perform a screen grab in Ubuntu, and eventually track mouse clicks and keyboard presses (although that's a slightly different question).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have GTK, then you can use the [gtk.gdk.Display](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gdkdisplay.html) class to do most of the work. It controls the keyboard/mouse pointer grabs a set of `gtk.gdk.Screen` objects.

Comment: Example of use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69645/take-a-screenshot-via-a-python-script-linux/782768#782768

Answer (score 3):

Check out [GNU LDTP](http://ldtp.freedesktop.org/wiki/):

> GNU/Linux Desktop Testing Project (GNU
>   LDTP) is aimed at producing high
>   quality test automation framework
>   [...]

Especially [Writing LDTP test scripts in Python scripting language](http://ldtp.freedesktop.org/wiki/LDTP_test_scripts_in_python)

Comment: Thanks Benji, I'll be having a look at this as well.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the screen grab, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69645/take-a-screenshot-via-a-python-script-linux/782768#782768).  That worked for me.  Other answers to the same question might be of interest as well.

Answer (score -1):

Check out the [RobotFramework](http://code.google.com/p/robotframework/). I do not know if it will do the same things as JavaRobot, or if it will do more. But it is easy and very flexible to use.

Comment: RobotFramework can be used outside of web automation. Selenium is just one of the drivers