# How can I control the keyboard and mouse with Python?

Tags: python, linux, awtrobot

How can I control the mouse and keyboard in Python?

The idea is to do the same as the [Robot() class](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) in Java. Be able to say: move the mouse from here to here, click there, write that whatever is on the screen.

For Windows there is win32api but I'm using mainly Linux.

For Linux there is Xlib but does it works for keyboard as well? (found only reference to the mouse)

Is there a cross-platform solution? (Linux, Windows and even OS X would be the great.)

Comment: Python's powerful, but I don't think it's powerful enough to allow you to control a keyboard and mouse. I'd love it if you could actually make my mouse zoom across my desk using Python, but I don't think it's going to happen. ;-)

Comment: a good solution for windows only
http://www.python-forum.org/pythonforum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=8976
I'm looking for the same for linux or cross-platform

Comment: Hm. May be You want emulating user action?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a Python equivalent to Java's AWT Robot class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860013/is-there-a-python-equivalent-to-javas-awt-robot-class)

Comment: Related: [Controlling mouse with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1181464/55075).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which is the easiest way to simulate keyboard and mouse on Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2791839/which-is-the-easiest-way-to-simulate-keyboard-and-mouse-on-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the mouse, I've found [pymouse](http://code.google.com/p/pymouse/) which seems to work (I haven't fully tried it, a small hack needed for the click, cf the issues)

for the keyboard, I'm not sure Xlib can do the job. I'm still looking on how to write something but you can catch key event as explained [here](http://www.larsen-b.com/Article/184.html) or in C [here](http://danielbaggio.blogspot.com/2008/04/generating-keypresses-on-linux.html) using Xlib (but I don't know C).

[here](http://www.python-forum.org/pythonforum/viewtopic.php?p=43596#p43596) is an example working on gnome only (not good enough yet)

In pymouse, they have a nice way to make it work on the 3 different platform but needs to make 3 code...

Answer (score 6):

I use dogtail (https://fedorahosted.org/dogtail/) to do such things, using this I have created an automated testing framework for my Linux(Ubuntu) app. That framework clicks buttons and types into text fields.

see the gedit example, https://fedorahosted.org/dogtail/browser/examples/gedit-test-utf8-procedural-api.py

So just use dogtail e.g

```
dogtail.rawinput.click(100, 100)
```

Comment: great, the rawinput module seems to have everything I need thanks a lot. I read that for the function to really test apps (detecting menus,...) work only for gnome.
Does the rawinput module work for other GUI ? (anyway it's open source, I can have a look)

Comment: do you know why if I do a dogtail.rawinput.click(x, y) I have to do a dogtail.rawinput.pressKey('a') otherwise nothing happens ???

Comment: I've send a bug report. can you try the piece of code ? https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=605302

Comment: it works for me on Ubuntu 9.10 32bit, not on Debian Sid amd64 and Archlinux amd64. A bug from the 64 bit version ?

Comment: is there anything alike for windows?

Answer (score 3):

I can advise you [PyAutoGUI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyAutoGUI), it allows to full control Mouse and Keyboard and get Screenshots and even you can locate images within the screen (like: where is the button?), very useful to automate clicks dynamically. It works for Windows, macOS, and Linux.

For example:

```
>>> import pyautogui
>>> screenWidth, screenHeight = pyautogui.size()
>>> pyautogui.moveTo(screenWidth / 2, screenHeight / 2)
```

Check out the [Introduction page](http://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html).

Answer (score 2):

This totally works... on a Mac at least.  This is for a click AND drag, etc.. but can be retrofitted accordingly.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import time
from Quartz.CoreGraphics import * # imports all of the top-level symbols in the module

def mouseEvent(type, posx, posy):
    theEvent = CGEventCreateMouseEvent(None, type, (posx,posy), kCGMouseButtonLeft)
    CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, theEvent)
def mousemove(posx,posy):
    mouseEvent(kCGEventMouseMoved, posx,posy);
def mouseclickdn(posx,posy):
    mouseEvent(kCGEventLeftMouseDown, posx,posy);
def mouseclickup(posx,posy):
    mouseEvent(kCGEventLeftMouseUp, posx,posy);
def mousedrag(posx,posy):
    mouseEvent(kCGEventLeftMouseDragged, posx,posy);

ourEvent = CGEventCreate(None);
currentpos=CGEventGetLocation(ourEvent); # Save current mouse position
mouseclickdn(60, 100);
mousedrag(60, 300);
mouseclickup(60, 300);
time.sleep(1);
mousemove(int(currentpos.x),int(currentpos.y)); # Restore mouse position
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an interessting Thread from Python Forum for you:
[Python Forum](http://www.python-forum.org/pythonforum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=8976)

Edit:
There was also an interessting question on stackoverflow regarding mouse control...maybe it is a good starting point..
[Mouse Control with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181464/controlling-mouse-with-python)

One of the Answers is refering to an Linux example...which heads you to an nice blog entry.

Comment: funny, I just send the same link to Dominic Rodger. It works on windows only I think (windll.user32.SetCursorPos doesn't sound good)

Answer (score 1):

For console try ncurses or slang. In other situation try PyQt, PyGtk, TkInter.

ALL of this solution ARE cross-platform and work almost anywhere.

Comment: it's already sad that I can't find a solution for windows and linux so a different solution if you are using Gtk or Qt seems not good. and anyway I don't understand what you say to use. Which method ? how ?...

Comment: Why Gtk or Qt seems for You not good? TkInter as far as I know is embedded in python by default!!!

Comment: Hm. May be You want emulating user action?

Comment: yes that's basically what I want to do. I want to be able to say go from here to here, clic there and write that whatever there is on the screen. Can I do it with PyQtk, PyGtk or PkInter ?

Comment: It MUST be available via PyGtk. about other toolkit i'm not sure.

Comment: found this thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860013/a-python-equivilent-to-java-robot which also advice to use gtk. But I still don't see how to move the mouse or send keyboard event. I see only function to catch event

Comment: http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gdkdisplay.html#method-gdkdisplay--put-event

Answer (score 1):

> For linux there is Xlib but does it works for keyboard as well? (found only reference to the mouse)

Yes, it work for keyboard also.

Comment: great and I think that Xlib is more generic than gtk (cf xlib's page on wikipedia) but same as for pygtk, I don't see the function to do it...

Comment: ok found with Xlib : pymouse for the mouse and here (http://www.tuxisalive.com/tux-droid-forum/tux-gadgets/245877021) for the keyboard

Answer (score 1):

A cross platform solution on linux, windows and mac is autopy.
https://github.com/msanders/autopy/

It allows controlling mouse and keyboard, taking screenshots, and finding small bitmaps on larger bitmaps and should be very convenient if you want to automate some gui application you have no control on.