# Opening new tab is not working with selenium +python3

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have used below lines in my script to open new tab.
But it is not working now.

```
body = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body")
body.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 't')
```

Can someone assist me further.

Browser Used: Chrome

Comment: Maybe try send_keys on `driver`, not on `body`. You want to send this message to your browser, not content of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try below:-

```
body.send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + 't')
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: There is one more way to handle keyboard even in python. refer this :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860013/is-there-a-python-equivalent-to-javas-awt-robot-class