# How to dismiss print dialog in selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, robotframework

I am trying to render a page which on load automatically shows the print dialog. I want to skip it using selenium. I searched on internet but couldn't find any suitable example since most of example handles javascript alert not windows alert.

I also install python `robotframework` because many people suggested it but couldn't find any example for that either.

My question is how to dismiss windows alert using selenium and robotframework in python?

NOTE: This question is in continuation of my previous question. [python selenium not updating pop up window url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37204246/python-selenium-not-updating-pop-up-window-url)

Answer (score 1):

I could avoid the printing window by overriding the `window.print` function:

```
driver.execute_script("window.print = function(){};")
```

Comment: Place it after the get command and before the click action. Note that each reload/refresh of the page will reset the print function.

Comment: There is no click function. The print dialog appears automatically on page load. I just want to skip it. I tried putting it both after and before the but it does not skip the print dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Using Firefox you could set some profile options that effectively silence the print dialog popup.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("print.always_print_silent", True)
profile.set_preference("print.show_print_progress", False)

driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
driver.get("http://www.google.com")

# Send print instruction
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body")
elem.send_keys(Keys.COMMAND, "p")
```

Comment: this will accept the print dialog and will print the page. I want to skip/decline it without printing the page.