# Sending data to a Window with AutoIt Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, autoit

I am using Selenium and AutoIT to upload images to a site.
Now I need to choose a file from the "File Upload" Window in Firefox and click Enter.
So this is the AutoIT part of the code:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/ul[1]/li/button").click()
    autoit.win_wait_active("File Upload", 5)
    autoit.send(os.path.join(mpath,"1.jpg"))
    autoit.send("{ENTER}")
```

This script works fine
Now the problem is the Window needs to be active on my computer in order for the file to be uploaded and so I cannot do any other work while the script is running.
How do I send the same data without making the window active?

Comment: Have you tried Robot Method ?

Comment: Selenium supports file upload, there's no need to use AutoIt.

Comment: @Florent B. I don't think Selenium supports File Upload through a Window. I mean I cannot select the Firefox Upload window with Selenium as far as I have read the docs.

Comment: @KishanPatel What is the Robot Method? Sorry I am a little new to python.

Comment: @user2726634, yes you can upload a file with Selenium with element.sendKeys("full file path"). Note that the element needs to be the `<input>` and not the button. It is documented and I've also tested it may times.

Comment: @FlorentB. Yea I know that input method. But this is a Flash upload. So there is no place to put the location of the file. I just click Upload and the File Upload window opens up.

Comment: Robot Class is there to upload files. Robot method basically listens to your mouse and keyboard actions so you can easily handles pop-ups which are windows based and not browser based. I don't know about python.Hope this helps you. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860013/is-there-a-python-equivalent-to-javas-awt-robot-class
But you can refer

Comment: @FlorentB, I would try to disable the Flash plugin and see if there is an alternative input tag. The Flash component might also have an upload function to directly upload a file.

Answer (score 2):

use this instead:

```
    autoit.win_wait("[CLASS:#32770;TITLE:Open]", 60)
    autoit.control_send("[CLASS:#32770;TITLE:Open]", "Edit1", os.path.join(mpath,"1.jpg"))
    autoit.control_click("[CLASS:#32770;TITLE:Open]", "Button1")
```