# I can't focus on upload button to upload resume

Tags: python, selenium

I can't focus on upload button to upload resume.

```html
<div id="uploadCredential" campaignid="6ecdba81-5485-11e8-8fbf-bc764e1156ea" class="                                                              ">
   <a href="#">
     <i class="icon-laptop"></i>
      Upload Resume
     </a>
</div>
```

**URL:** [Website Link](https://opportunities.matrixres.com/l/recruiting/jobapplication/a233d19e-4272-11e8-bc77-bc764e10a8d2/7e716ae9-54eb-11e8-ab67-bc764e10a8d2/false?step=2&checkmin=1)

Comment: Why do you need to _focus_? Code trials and error stack trace please.

Comment: what happens when you use linkText("Upload Resume") ?

Comment: Find XPATH for `id="uploadCredential"`, then `click()` it .

Comment: @Mika72 : if ID is already given then why should we use XPATH ?

Comment: its working with linktext

Comment: Query has been resolved ?

Comment: I have provided the same answer , you can accept it ! So this question would be closed !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code :

```
driver.find_elements_by_link_text("Upload Resume").click()
```

Comment: just clicking on it not uploading Resume i used this code **driver.find_elements_by_link_text("Upload Resume").send_keys("C:/Users/user/Desktop/Resume.docx")**

Comment: for uploading you might wanna use AutoIT script .

Comment: how to use without autoit

Comment: You are clicking on a upload resume button , that button is a webelement , selenium can interact with it ! However, after clicking you must have seen the native window which selenium can’t interact with. You will have to go for 3rd party application like AutoIT. Still if you do not want to go with AutoIT you can use ROBOT class for the same. Note that robot class is highly unstable as compared to AutoIT

Comment: If you have GTK, then you can use the gtk.gdk.Display class to do most of the work. It controls the keyboard/mouse pointer grabs a set of gtk.gdk.Screen objects.

Comment: Check out this SO :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860013/is-there-a-python-equivalent-to-javas-awt-robot-class?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa and This SO : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69645/take-a-screenshot-via-a-python-script-linux/782768#782768

Comment: i am pyperclip for copy and paste coverletter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170889/discussion-between-bhupathi-turaga-and-cruisepandey).

Comment: @bhupathituraga  : Sure !

Answer (score 2):

As per the *HTML* you have shared the element with text as **Upload Resume** is within the `<a>` tag and to click on the element you can use either of the following *Locator Strategies* :

- `link_text` :

  ```
  driver.find_elements_by_link_text("Upload Resume").click()
  ```
- `css_selector` :

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div#uploadCredential > a").click()
  ```
- `xpath` :

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='uploadCredential']/a").click()
  ```

Comment: sorry @cruisepandey given answer first