# is there any other way except sendKeys to upload file to a website?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I am actually trying to upload a picture to:
https://www.remove.bg/upload
But the problem is that I can't find an input tag to upload files using the sendKeys keyword,
looking forward to any solution.

Comment: You can send the path to that upload button.

Comment: @NandanA : There's no input tag as attribute type and value file, so no he can not do that in this case

Comment: It gave me error that there is attribute for this webelement

Comment: @cruisepandey is there any other to solve this issue

Comment: @ShaiqParacha : may be auto it is your best shot as far as I know, but it will only work in WIndows, not any platform

Comment: @cruisepandey Actually, I was trying to find some way which more likely to be done using Python by the way Thanks for that option

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860013/is-there-a-python-equivalent-to-javas-awt-robot-class see this