# Take screenshots **quickly** from python

Tags: python, image, optimization, performance, screen-scraping

A `PIL.Image.grab()` takes about 0.5 seconds. That's just to get data from the screen to my app, without any processing on my part. [FRAPS](http://www.fraps.com/), on the other hand, can take screenshots up to 30 FPS. Is there any way for me to do the same from a Python program? If not, how about from a  C program? (I could interface it w/ the Python program, potentially...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want fast screenshots, you must use a lower level API, like DirectX or GTK. There are Python wrappers for those, like [DirectPython](http://directpython.sourceforge.net/) and [PyGTK](http://www.pygtk.org/). Some samples I've found follow:

- [PyGTK sample](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/8qe1t/fast_x11_screenshots_in_python_see_comment/)
- [Windows and DirectX samples](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/screencap.aspx)

Comment: thanks for the start! so PIL takes 0.35 seconds (I timed it). The GTK sample in the 1st one is the same - 0.35. But the GTK without converting to PIL is 0.11, so that's a start...

Comment: Check this out, it has most of the alternatives...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69645/take-a-screenshot-via-a-python-script-linux

Comment: Great tool, but unfortunately not working with Python 3

Comment: A good alternative that is quicker and Python 3 compliant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44925891/1117028