# How to capture screen from fullscreen(!) VPython window?

Tags: python, screenshot, vpython

I am using VPython to visualize some data from a computer simulation.
I want to make a movie out of the VPython output. Therefore I tried to make screenshots from the vpython output window. I want to capture the output window in fullscreen mode. This way i don't need to crop the window frame. I tried ImageGrab.grab() ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3260811/2056153)) and win32gui ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3278356/2056153)), but both methods capture the desktop instead of the fullscreen window.

Methods `screenshot` and `_get_windows_bytitle` [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3278356/2056153)

```
windowtitle = 'sometitlename'
newscene = display(fullscreen=True,title=windowtitle)
newscene.cursor.visible=false
newscene.select()

b = box()
rate(1)
screenshot(_get_windows_bytitle(windowtitle)[0])
```

Same problem with `ImageGrab.grab`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find any solution, so I used the workaround by cropping the window manually.

```
disp = display(width=1000, height=1040)
displayrect = (int(round(disp.x))+8, int(round(disp.y))+30, int(round(disp.width))-16, int(round(disp.height))-38)
ImageGrab.grab(displayrect)
```

I am not really happy with that, since it's quite messy to hardcode the window border width/height (I won't use the win32 module for that)