# Can python get the screen shot of a specific window?

Tags: python

For example, I am running a java program. Can I use python to get the content(screenshot) of this java program? Not the full screen, just the java program.

I have seen this module, but it required a parameter of "where the program window is":

```
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # part of the screen
    im=ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(10,10,510,510)) # X1,Y1,X2,Y2
    im.show()
#-#
```

But this may not be what I am seeking since it requires the bounding_box.

Comment: You could detect what window you want to capture and find it's height, width, and coords...

Comment: @MooingRawr Thanks for your idea. But how? I originally thought there may be a method I can provide a window title or program ID

Answer (score 33):

There are multiple ways to do that. The code for these will require modification based on your needs, so I will put in some pointers to the high level methods and libraries:

1. You can directly use GUI-automation tools such as `Pyautogui` to press `Alt`+`PrntScreen` and transfer the data from clipboard into a variable (http://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#keyboard-keys)
2. You can use pywin32 and PIL to grab the image of a certain window ([How to Get a Window or Fullscreen Screenshot in Python 3k? (without PIL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3260559/how-to-get-a-window-or-fullscreen-screenshot-in-python-3k-without-pil))
3. You can use imagemagik to grab screenshots of a single window (https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=24702)
4. You can use `Pyautogui.locateOnScreen(“Sceenshot.PNG”) to find the tuple which will contain the boundaries of the window for your java app. Then you can  pass it to your function`img.ImageGrab.grab(bbox)`

Answer (score 8):

A example to get the content(screenshot) of a specific window with the help of the `pygetwindow` [module](https://pypi.org/project/PyGetWindow/).

```
import pygetwindow
import time
import os
import pyautogui
import PIL

# get screensize
x,y = pyautogui.size()
print(f"width={x}\theight={y}")

x2,y2 = pyautogui.size()
x2,y2=int(str(x2)),int(str(y2))
print(x2//2)
print(y2//2)

# find new window title
z1 = pygetwindow.getAllTitles()
time.sleep(1)
print(len(z1))
# test with pictures folder
os.startfile("C:\\Users\\yourname\\Pictures")
time.sleep(1)
z2 = pygetwindow.getAllTitles()
print(len(z2))
time.sleep(1)
z3 = [x for x in z2 if x not in z1]
z3 = ''.join(z3)
time.sleep(3)

# also able to edit z3 to specified window-title string like: "Sublime Text (UNREGISTERED)"
my = pygetwindow.getWindowsWithTitle(z3)[0]
# quarter of screen screensize
x3 = x2 // 2
y3 = y2 // 2
my.resizeTo(x3,y3)
# top-left
my.moveTo(0, 0)
time.sleep(3)
my.activate()
time.sleep(1)

# save screenshot
p = pyautogui.screenshot()
p.save(r'C:\\Users\\yourname\\Pictures\\\\p.png')

# edit screenshot
im = PIL.Image.open('C:\\Users\\yourname\\Pictures\\p.png')
im_crop = im.crop((0, 0, x3, y3))
im_crop.save('C:\\Users\\yourname\\Pictures\\p.jpg', quality=100)

# close window
time.sleep(1)
my.close()
```

Comment: Looks good. However, instead of taking a screenshot of the full screen and cutting out the desired beforehand activated, resized and repositioned window, isn't there a way to directly get only the content of the desired window by name (maybe even when it is partly or fully covered by other windows, and maybe even without putting it into front)?

Answer (score -1):

I think this will work:

```
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab
import pygetwindow as gw

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Get the window with the title "Your Window Title"
    window = gw.getWindowsWithTitle("Your Window Title")[0]

    # Get the window coordinates
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = window.left, window.top, window.left + window.width, window.top + window.height

    # Capture the specified window
    im = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(x1, y1, x2, y2))
    im.show()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This will only work if window is visible and on the top of other windows, that is not always true.