# how to perform OCR on running program window

Tags: ocr

I need to extract information, text and numbers, from a running program, let's say a game.

So I was wondering if there is a way to perform OCR on a program's window, "watch" it continuously, and if some conditions are met perform OCR on specific zones of the window to extract text.

I admit this might sound weird but that's what I need to do!    :)

Thanks for any tip you might have on this topic.
G.

Answer (score 3):

Although I am not sure how feasible it is doing this in real time for full screen, but if the window size is small, the text is large then it can be done faster, more accurate.

You need to set a timer to skip frames, recapture and rerun the OCR model to continuously process frames. To get more `accurate results` use a larger image or tune ocr parameters. If the window is in the background when capturing you need to bring it in front otherwise it will get wrong window with my code implementation.

A helpful implementation, [Can python get the screen shot of a specific window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40809729/can-python-get-the-screen-shot-of-a-specific-window/64489036#64489036)

This is my simple implementation for grabbing a single specified window and processing with `EasyOCR`. The text and output location will be printed on console.

#### Code

```
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab
import pygetwindow as gw
import numpy as np
import easyocr
import cv2


# need to run only once to load model into memory
print("Loading Model")
reader = easyocr.Reader(['ch_sim','en'], gpu = True)


# Get by either window title, active window or window directly
print(gw.getAllTitles())
print(gw.getActiveWindow())
print(gw.getAllWindows())


# Provide desired window title manually or with title index of getAllTitles
tmp = gw.getWindowsWithTitle('untitled1 – test2.py PyCharm')


# Print window location, title
print(int(np.abs(tmp[0].left)), int(np.abs(tmp[0].top)), int(np.abs(tmp[0].right)), int(np.abs(tmp[0].bottom)))
print(tmp[0])


# grab fullscreen
#im = ImageGrab.grab()


# grab certain portion of selected window
print("Grabbing Window")
im = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(int(np.abs(tmp[0].left)), int(np.abs(tmp[0].top)), int(np.abs(tmp[0].right)), int(np.abs(tmp[0].bottom))))  # X1,Y1,X2,Y2



# save image file and process that image
#im.save("window1.jpg")
#result = reader.readtext('window1.jpg')



# Resize the image to certain percent of original image
print("Resizing Image")
im_np = np.array(im)
scale_percent = 50
width = int(im_np.shape[1] * scale_percent / 100)
height = int(im_np.shape[0] * scale_percent / 100)
dim = (width, height)
im_resized = cv2.resize(im_np, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)



# process the grabbed image directly as numpy array
print("Processing with OCR")
result = reader.readtext(np.array(im_resized))
print(result)



# For each detected text draw bounding box in image and print text, location
i = 0
for r in result:
    print("################################")
    print(r[0][0], r[0][1], r[0][2], r[0][3])
    print("FOUND:")
    print(r[1])
    print("################################")

    x1=min(r[0][0][0], r[0][1][0], r[0][2][0], r[0][3][0])
    x2=max(r[0][0][0], r[0][1][0], r[0][2][0], r[0][3][0])
    y1=min(r[0][0][1], r[0][1][1], r[0][2][1], r[0][3][1])
    y2=max(r[0][0][1], r[0][1][1], r[0][2][1], r[0][3][1])

    image = cv2.rectangle(im_resized, (int(x1), int(y1)), (int(x2), int(y2)), (0, 255, 255), 3)

    cv2.imshow("window_name", image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.imwrite("images/img_" + str(i) + ".jpg", image)
    i += 1
```

#### Partial Console Output

```
################################
[409, 117] [465, 117] [465, 129] [409, 129]
FOUND:
r[u][1][u],
################################
################################
[469, 117] [525, 117] [525, 129] [469, 129]
FOUND:
r[u][2][0],
################################
################################
[529, 117] [587, 117] [587, 129] [529, 129]
FOUND:
r[u][][0]1
################################
```

#### Image Output

[image]

There is no mention of platform or programming language implementation. Most libraries here claim to be cross platform. Look into these for getting window location, selected window, window control, screenshot.

https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui

https://github.com/asweigart/pygetwindow

https://github.com/ponty/pyscreenshot

An easy python based OCR,

https://github.com/JaidedAI/EasyOCR

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this in streaming?

If you can record the screen you can divide the video in frames and ocr frame per frame will do the rest.

Comment: that would be the best option for me since I need to take actions if some "onscreen" conditions are met. 
ex. If the word "next" is found in a specific region of the screen I need to do action A