# Capture video stream from everything displayed in a specific window

Tags: python, windows, winapi, video, gdi

We can capture a video stream from a webcam with:

```
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
    success, frame = camera.read()
    if success:
        buffer = cv2.imencode('.png', frame)
```

Is there a similar way in Python to capture a video stream of another window (at a 30 fps rate), even if this window is not in foreground? (Another window is on top)

I thought about methods mentioned in [Can python get the screen shot of a specific window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40809729/can-python-get-the-screen-shot-of-a-specific-window) but I doubt it will work because the window to be captured is not in foreground. Techincally it is hidden by another window on top of it.

Is there a more direct way with GDI WinApi?

Comment: [Screen capture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/screen-capture).

Comment: Good idea @IInspectable, I'll have a look. Out of curiosity, what were the possibilities before this relatively-new API? I imagine this was possible since older versions of Windows, which were the names of these APIs?

Comment: *"what were the possibilities before this relatively-new API?"* - Hooking into the compositor.

Comment: Would you have an example about how to do this @IInspectable?

Comment: Does [Desktop Duplication API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3ddxgi/desktop-dup-api) or [Capturing an Image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/capturing-an-image)(GDI) work for you?

Comment: @YangXiaoPo-MSFT Interesting solutions. Which solution is the best if it has to work on Win10 and also Win7 (I know it's EOL but some clients still use it and I have to deal with this). Is the GDI solution better in this case? If you want, you can post an answer with a code example, it would be interesting for future reference. Thanks!

Comment: @YangXiaoPo-MSFT PS: does the GDI solution work also if the window to be captured is in the background, and another window is on top of it?

Answer (score 0):

Although GDI can capture the window which in the background, some area cannot be captured for some windows Or you can just capture the client area. If possible, use [Screen capture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/screen-capture) as @IInspectable suggested.
The following code is adapted from document sample [Capturing an Image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/capturing-an-image).

```
int CaptureAnImage(HWND hWnd)
{
    HDC hdcScreen;
    HDC hdcWindow;
    HDC hdcMemDC = NULL;
    HBITMAP hbmScreen = NULL;
    BITMAP bmpScreen;
    DWORD dwBytesWritten = 0;
    DWORD dwSizeofDIB = 0;
    HANDLE hFile = NULL;
    char* lpbitmap = NULL;
    HANDLE hDIB = NULL;
    DWORD dwBmpSize = 0;

    // Retrieve the handle to a display device context for the client 
    // area of the window. 
    //hdcScreen = GetDC(NULL);
    /**/
    HWND hWindow = FindWindow(NULL, L"*Untitled - Notepad");
    //HWND hWindow = GetDesktopWindow();
    hdcScreen = GetWindowDC(hWindow);

    RECT r{};
    GetWindowRect(hWindow, &r);

    hdcWindow = GetDC(hWnd);

    // Create a compatible DC, which is used in a BitBlt from the window DC.
    hdcMemDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcWindow);

    if (!hdcMemDC)
    {
        MessageBox(hWnd, TEXT("CreateCompatibleDC has failed"), TEXT("Failed"), MB_OK);
        goto done;
    }

    // Get the client area for size calculation.
    RECT rcClient;
    GetClientRect(hWnd, &rcClient);

    // This is the best stretch mode.
    SetStretchBltMode(hdcWindow, HALFTONE);

    // The source DC is the entire screen, and the destination DC is the current window (HWND).
    if (!StretchBlt(hdcWindow,
        0, 0,
        rcClient.right, rcClient.bottom,
        hdcScreen,
        0, 0,
        //GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN),
        r.right - r.left,
        r.bottom - r.top,
        //GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN),
        SRCCOPY))
    {
        MessageBox(hWnd, TEXT("StretchBlt has failed"), TEXT("Failed"), MB_OK);
        goto done;
    }

    // Create a compatible bitmap from the Window DC.
    hbmScreen = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcWindow, rcClient.right - rcClient.left, rcClient.bottom - rcClient.top);

    if (!hbmScreen)
    {
        MessageBox(hWnd, TEXT("CreateCompatibleBitmap Failed"), TEXT("Failed"), MB_OK);
        goto done;
    }

    // Select the compatible bitmap into the compatible memory DC.
    SelectObject(hdcMemDC, hbmScreen);

    // Bit block transfer into our compatible memory DC.
    if (!BitBlt(hdcMemDC,
        0, 0,
        rcClient.right - rcClient.left, rcClient.bottom - rcClient.top,
        hdcWindow,
        0, 0,
        SRCCOPY))
    {
        MessageBox(hWnd, TEXT("BitBlt has failed"), TEXT("Failed"), MB_OK);
        goto done;
    }

    // Get the BITMAP from the HBITMAP.
    GetObject(hbmScreen, sizeof(BITMAP), &bmpScreen);

    BITMAPFILEHEADER   bmfHeader;
    BITMAPINFOHEADER   bi;

    bi.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    bi.biWidth = bmpScreen.bmWidth;
    bi.biHeight = bmpScreen.bmHeight;
    bi.biPlanes = 1;
    bi.biBitCount = 32;
    bi.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    bi.biSizeImage = 0;
    bi.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
    bi.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
    bi.biClrUsed = 0;
    bi.biClrImportant = 0;

    dwBmpSize = ((bmpScreen.bmWidth * bi.biBitCount + 31) / 32) * 4 * bmpScreen.bmHeight;

    // Starting with 32-bit Windows, GlobalAlloc and LocalAlloc are implemented as wrapper functions that 
    // call HeapAlloc using a handle to the process's default heap. Therefore, GlobalAlloc and LocalAlloc 
    // have greater overhead than HeapAlloc.
    hDIB = GlobalAlloc(GHND, dwBmpSize);
    lpbitmap = (char*)GlobalLock(hDIB);

    // Gets the "bits" from the bitmap, and copies them into a buffer 
    // that's pointed to by lpbitmap.
    GetDIBits(hdcWindow, hbmScreen, 0,
        (UINT)bmpScreen.bmHeight,
        lpbitmap,
        (BITMAPINFO*)&bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

    // A file is created, this is where we will save the screen capture.
    hFile = CreateFile(TEXT("captureqwsx.bmp"),
        GENERIC_WRITE,
        0,
        NULL,
        CREATE_ALWAYS,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

    // Add the size of the headers to the size of the bitmap to get the total file size.
    dwSizeofDIB = dwBmpSize + sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);

    // Offset to where the actual bitmap bits start.
    bmfHeader.bfOffBits = (DWORD)sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + (DWORD)sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);

    // Size of the file.
    bmfHeader.bfSize = dwSizeofDIB;

    // bfType must always be BM for Bitmaps.
    bmfHeader.bfType = 0x4D42; // BM.

    WriteFile(hFile, (LPSTR)&bmfHeader, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), &dwBytesWritten, NULL);
    WriteFile(hFile, (LPSTR)&bi, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), &dwBytesWritten, NULL);
    WriteFile(hFile, (LPSTR)lpbitmap, dwBmpSize, &dwBytesWritten, NULL);

    // Unlock and Free the DIB from the heap.
    GlobalUnlock(hDIB);
    GlobalFree(hDIB);

    // Close the handle for the file that was created.
    CloseHandle(hFile);

    // Clean up.
done:
    DeleteObject(hbmScreen);
    DeleteObject(hdcMemDC);
    ReleaseDC(NULL, hdcScreen);
    ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdcWindow);

    return 0;
}
```

[image]
[image]