# Python take a screenshot of the screen and save it to a buffer

Tags: python, opencv, buffer, python-imaging-library, screenshot

I want to take a screenshot of the screen and save it to a buffer as a photo(`X.jpg`) and later I can use the `cv2(opencv)` to read the same image from the buffer.
i act as follow:

## Edit My code:

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
from io import BytesIO

ii = ImageGrab.grab()
with BytesIO() as output:
    ii.save(output,format="JPEG")# This line has an error 
    cam = output.getvalue()
result, frame = cv2.imencode('.jpg', cam, encode_param)
```

i get this Errors:

```
TypeError: img is not a numpy array, neither a scalar
```

thank you

Comment: go through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3260559/how-to-get-a-window-or-fullscreen-screenshot-in-python-3k-without-pil)

Comment: Can you explain what the problem is and show any error messages you get? Also comments in python start with # not //

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Get a Window or Fullscreen Screenshot in Python 3k? (without PIL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3260559/how-to-get-a-window-or-fullscreen-screenshot-in-python-3k-without-pil)

Comment: i edited my question

Comment: If you already saved it to disk as JPEG, why not just read the contents of the file directly into a buffer (rather than decoding it by `imread` and then encoding back with `imencode`)? Or even better, it's [trivial](https://stackoverflow.com/q/384759/3962537) to convert PIL image to a numpy array. Then just directly `imencode` that, instead of the round trip to the filesystem.

Comment: @Dan Mašek i want to send screenshot to another system by socket,i want to save that screenshot to buffer so i can read and send by socket,you say i can convert PIL image to numpy array, How? The point here is how can I convert a grabed image into numpy array?

Comment: It's explained in the post I refer to. Or you can even just use [PIL to encode to a buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646286/python-pil-how-to-write-png-image-to-string).

Comment: @Dan Mašek According to [PIL to encode to a buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646286/python-pil-how-to-write-png-image-to-string) i get this error `TypeError: img is not a numpy array, neither a scalar`

Comment: If you changed your code, and are getting a different error, then [edit] the question and update it appropriately.

Comment: @Dan Mašek i edit my question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185377/discussion-between-jozef-and-dan-masek).

Comment: The last line is redundant, `cam` already is a buffer containing the JPEG stream, so there's no point trying to encode it again with `cv2.imencode`. If it's the `save` that's failing... whoa... maybe the `grab()` failed to get anything?

Comment: @Dan Mašek The `grab()` is work correctly because whene i use `ii.save("E:\\aaa.jpg",format="JPEG",quality=100,optimize=True)` I do not get any errors and everything works properly

Comment: Sorry, can't reproduce that problem locally, works as expected.

Comment: @Dan Mašek Thank you for the time you spent

Answer (score 2):

Here is a demo:

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
from io import BytesIO
import numpy as np 
import cv2

## (1) Grab the rgb frame as PIL.Image
ii = ImageGrab.grab()
print(type(ii)) # <class 'PIL.Image.Image'>

## (2) Convert PIL.Image to np.array 
rgb = np.array(ii)
print(type(ii)) # <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

## (3) Convert into BGR and display 
bgr = cv2.cvtColor(rgb, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
cv2.imshow("frame", bgr)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```