# Python: Is there a way to grayscale screen with cv2?

Tags: python, opencv

Is it possible to grayscale a portion of your screen in real time with cv2?

I know how grayscale images but can we grayscale the screen?
if you know how to Geryscale a portion of your screen then please add code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a Way to gray-scale a portion of my screen!

my code:

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
import cv2
from numpy import array
import time

while True:
    Screen = array(ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(13, 32,805, 623)))
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(Screen, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    edges = cv2.Canny(gray, 20, 30)
    edges_high_thresh = cv2.Canny(gray, 60, 120)

    
    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff

    if k == 27:
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
    
    
    cv2.imshow('Frame', edges)
```

Answer (score 2):

`cv2` doesn't have write access to your screen buffer and therefore can't change the color of what you see on your screen. You should be able to take a screenshot and manipulate it, however. See [Python take a screenshot of the screen and save it to a buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53820369/python-take-a-screenshot-of-the-screen-and-save-it-to-a-buffer).