# Screenshot with selenium and python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, automation, screenshot

I need to take a screenshot of my entire screen for some automated tests I need to perform.

I was able to do this, using driver.get_screenshot_as_file , but the problem is that it only takes the picture of the web page, I need to get the whole picture from the browser, since the data I need to check is in the devtools.

Pic:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYwL8.png)

I need this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUorA.png)

Thankss!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the package `pyautogui` to get screenshot of the desktop on the os level. This take screenshot of the entire desktop rather than just the webpage.

```
import pyautogui

pyautogui.screenshot().save('screenshot.png')
```

Comment: Great this library, I didn't know it.


I get the following error, what can it be due to? I install pillow (pip install Pillow --upgrade)

   pyautogui.screenshot().save('aut.jpg')
  File "C:\Users\asd\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 144, in wrapper
    raise PyScreezeException('The Pillow package is required to use this function.')
pyscreeze.PyScreezeException: The Pillow package is required to use this function.

Comment: what version of Pillow do you now have?

Comment: can you try this in a clean virtual environment? I just tried it with `pip install Pillow --upgrade` and it works

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative to `pyautogui` would be `PIL`'s ImageGrab. The advantage is that you are able to specify a bounding box:

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
image = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=None) # bbox=None gives you the whole screen
image.save("your_browser.png")

# for later cv2 use:
import numpy
import cv2
image_cv2 = cv2.cvtColor(numpy.array(image), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

This also makes it possible to adapt to your browser's window size and only capture its specific window. You can get your browsers bounding box as shown in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3260811/20161430.

From a speed perspective, it doesn't seem to make much of a difference whether you are using `pyautogui` or `PIL`.