# Python windows 7 screenshot without PIL

Tags: python, image, windows-7, screenshot

I want to take a screenshot using python.

I have tried using PIL, but since I am using 64bit windows and python PIL does not work (I could only find 32bit PIL versions). I am using python 2.7.1 by the way.

I want to take a screenshot, it doesn't really matter how, as long as it can take more than 1 per second in speed. Preferably it should also be able to crop the area it takes a screenshot of, but that's not of the utmost importance.

The main problem seems to be I'm running on 64bit and a lot of things seem incompatible with that. I don't really want to move back to 32bit though if at all possible. 
Are there any programs or modules that can do this?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Get PIL for win-amd64-py2.7 at http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pil.

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
im = ImageGrab.grab()
im.save('screenshot.png')
```

Update: use pywin32 (http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) instead of PIL to take screenshots of multiple virtual screens:

```
import win32gui, win32ui, win32con, win32api
hwin = win32gui.GetDesktopWindow()
width = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_CXVIRTUALSCREEN)
height = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_CYVIRTUALSCREEN)
left = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_XVIRTUALSCREEN)
top = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_YVIRTUALSCREEN)
hwindc = win32gui.GetWindowDC(hwin)
srcdc = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(hwindc)
memdc = srcdc.CreateCompatibleDC()
bmp = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
bmp.CreateCompatibleBitmap(srcdc, width, height)
memdc.SelectObject(bmp)
memdc.BitBlt((0, 0), (width, height), srcdc, (left, top), win32con.SRCCOPY)
bmp.SaveBitmapFile(memdc, 'screenshot.bmp')
```

Comment: ... if (as I assume by the name) you are responsible for the linked site, then Kudos! I was going insane trying to properly compile SciPy in 64-bit ;-)

Comment: Thanks! That PIL version was exactly what I was looking for but could not find. With the win32gui how do you mean take screenshots of multiple virtual screens though? What I want to do is just repeatedly take a screenshot of a part of my screen, can PIL do that too or is pywin32 better for that? (And does pywin32 work with 64bit python/windows7? The name is kind of misleading :))

Comment: ImageGrab.grab() takes an optional bbox argument (http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/imagegrab.htm).

Comment: PyWin32 works on 64 bit Windows. I guess the "win32" part in PyWin32 refers to the Windows API, formerly called "Win32 API" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API).
The pywin32 code allows you to grab the whole desktop image in case you have multiple monitors, while PIL only grabs the main monitor. You can adjust the left, top, width, and height parameters to only grab parts of the screen.

Comment: second way worked for me perfectly ! But first one not work because of ImageGrab  : ImportError: No module named '_grabscreen', anyway Thx.

Answer (score 1):

32- or 64-bit Windows is irrelevant here; it is the 'bit-ness' of Python and its modules that matter. If you are running 32-bit-compiled Python, 32-bit-compiled PIL will work just fine on 64-bit Windows.

On the other hand, if you are running 64-bit-compiled Python, you need to find or custom-compile a 64-bit-compiled version of PIL to match.

**Edit:**

You can download a 64-bit-compiled version of PIL from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ - specifically, you want PIL-1.1.7.win-amd64-py2.7.‌exe

Comment: Ok, thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for but couldn't find.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem on PIL or pyscreenshot, here's how I solved it.

Right-click on python.exe, Properties, Compatibility tab, check 'Disable display scaling on high DPI settings'. Repeat for pythonw.exe.