# saving bitmap data to a file

Tags: python, winapi, screenshot, ctypes

i'm trying to take screenshot with python using only ctypes.

i get stuck after the bitblt.
do anyone have a code which saves the bitmap object into a file with ctypes in python?

this is the code i wrote so far:

```
import ctypes    
from ctypes import *    

   #Constants   
   SM_CXSCREEN = 0   
    SM_CYSCREEN = 1        
    SRCCOPY = 0xCC0020         
    user32 = ctypes.windll.user32       
    gdi32 = ctypes.windll.gdi32    


class BITMAPINFOHEADER(ctypes.Structure):    
    _fields_ = [    
        ('biSize', ctypes.c_uint32),        
        ('biWidth', ctypes.c_int),    
        ('biHeight', ctypes.c_int),    
        ('biPlanes', ctypes.c_short),    
        ('biBitCount', ctypes.c_short),    
        ('biCompression', ctypes.c_uint32),    
        ('biSizeImage', ctypes.c_uint32),    
        ('biXPelsPerMeter', ctypes.c_long),    
        ('biYPelsPerMeter', ctypes.c_long),    
        ('biClrUsed', ctypes.c_uint32),    
        ('biClrImportant', ctypes.c_uint32)    
    ]    



class BITMAPINFO(ctypes.Structure):    
    _fields_ = [    
        ('bmiHeader', BITMAPINFOHEADER),    
        ('bmiColors', ctypes.c_ulong * 3)    
    ]    


hDesktopWnd = user32.GetDesktopWindow()    
WinDC = user32.GetDC (hDesktopWnd)    
CopyDC = gdi32.CreateCompatibleDC (WinDC)    
hBitmap = gdi32.CreateCompatibleBitmap (WinDC,  1000, 1000)    
gdi32.SelectObject (CopyDC, hBitmap)    
gdi32.BitBlt(CopyDC,   0,0, 1000,   1000,   WinDC,  0, 0,   SRCCOPY);
```

i know that the next step will be somthing like:

```
lpbi = BITMAPINFO()    
ctypes.memset(ctypes.byref(lpbi), 0x00, ctypes.sizeof(lpbi))    
lpbi.bmiHeader.biSize = ctypes.sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER)    
gdi32.SelectObject (CopyDC, hBitmap)    

...
```

but it sucked and didn't work.
please help.

Comment: Is it possible for you to use PIL?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4589290/1052325

Comment: nope... only allowed to import ctypes

Comment: Here is an example of how to create an image file using pure python. It is not ctypes oriented, but luckily it may help you: http://www.python.org.br/wiki/ImagemTGA