# Memory leak / Python windows 7 screenshots

Tags: python, windows-7, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, screenshot

I have tried the following Python code on a dual monitor system (Windows7) to repeatedly save screenshots.
It generates 33 shots of 14.6MB (total 482MB) and then crash. Checking with Process Explorer I can see the amount of used memory raise to about 500MB.

My question is how to stop the memory leak?

```
import win32gui, win32ui, win32con, win32api
import time
import os


def my_capture(file_name):
    hwin = win32gui.GetDesktopWindow()
    width = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_CXVIRTUALSCREEN)
    height = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_CYVIRTUALSCREEN)
    left = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_XVIRTUALSCREEN)
    top = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_YVIRTUALSCREEN)
    hwindc = win32gui.GetWindowDC(hwin)
    srcdc = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(hwindc)
    memdc = srcdc.CreateCompatibleDC()
    bmp = win32ui.CreateBitmap()    
    bmp.CreateCompatibleBitmap(srcdc, width, height)
    memdc.SelectObject(bmp)
    memdc.BitBlt((0, 0), (width, height), srcdc, (left, top), win32con.SRCCOPY)
    bmp.SaveBitmapFile(memdc, file_name) # 'screenshot.bmp'


def captureAndSave(i):
    if i < 10:
        tmpStr = "00000" + str(i)
    elif i < 100:
        tmpStr = "0000" + str(i)
    elif i < 1000:
        tmpStr = "000" + str(i)
    elif i < 10000:
        tmpStr = "00" + str(i)
    elif i < 100000:
        tmpStr = "0" + str(i)
    else:
        tmpStr = str(i)

    my_capture(tmpStr + '.bmp')


def myMainLoop():
    i = 0
    while 1:
        i = i + 1
        captureAndSave(i)
        time.sleep(0.2)

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        myMainLoop()        # capure all monitor windows
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
```

---

I got the base code from: [Python windows 7 screenshot without PIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589206/python-windows-7-screenshot-without-pil):

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to clean up your bitmaps and DCs, adding something like this after the bitmap is saved;

```
win32gui.DeleteObject(bmp.GetHandle())
memdc.DeleteDC()
srcdc.DeleteDC()
win32gui.ReleaseDC(hwin, hwindc)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It works perfect after adding your clean up code.