# PIL and Python27 - Save a screengrab?

Tags: python, python-2.7, screenshot, python-imaging-library, clipboard

Here is the code

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
scrgrb = ImageGrab.grabclipboard()
scrgrbnum = 0

def saveimg():
    scrgrb.save("screengrab.jpeg + str(scrgrbnum + 1)", "JPEG")
    scrgrbnum = scrgrbnum + 1

saveimg()
```

And I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File
 "C:/Python27/Programs/screengrab", line 10, in <module>
     saveimg()   File "C:/Python27/Programs/screengrab", line 7, in saveimg
     scrgrb.save("screengrab.jpeg + str(scrgrbnum + 1)", "JPEG") AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'save'
```

Why can't I save a screengrab object?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
 import win32api, win32con, ImageGrab
 win32api.keybd_event(win32con.VK_SNAPSHOT, 1)
 im = ImageGrab.grabclipboard()
 im.save("screenshot.jpg", "JPEG")
```

I think the key here is importing the winapi too.

[Source](http://traviscrowder.com/web/python-windows-print-screen-save)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the answer, apparently

```
scrgrb = ImageGrab.grabclipboard()
```

Should actually be

```
scrgrb = ImageGrab.grab()
```

I found this on the top answer here [Python windows 7 screenshot without PIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589206/python-windows-7-screenshot-without-pil)

The documentation on the PIL website doesn't show this change -.-

Comment: i was going to suggest this too, it says this on http://forums.devshed.com/python-programming-11/python-print-screen-copy-from-clipboard-655043.html

Comment: Ah, cool, at least I know I've got it right, so I'll mark my answer correct, thankyou!