# Quickly take every n values from string python

Tags: python, bitmap

Firstly, I am aware that not using python for this application would help speed up my code. Unfortunately python is what I am most familiar with, and I have a somewhat limited amount of time for this project. Learning C or something similar is not practical for my situation.

So here is my problem. I have loaded a bitmap into python and extracted the pixel data, which I have stored as raw bytes in string form such as: "143 200 30 -1" (It's a byte with value 143, not the 3 characters it would take to write the number 143).

What I am looking to do is remove every fourth byte from the string. The fourth byte is the alpha channel, which I don't need for my application. Here is the code I have so far, it takes a section of the image of dimension blockSizeX x blockSizeY, located at position blockY and blockX, and strips out the alpha channel in the process :

```
def getScreenBlockFaster(bmpstr, imgWidth):
    pixelData = ''
    pixelCoord = (blockY * blockSizeY * imgWidth + blockSizeX * blockX)* 4
    for y in range(blockSizeY * 4):
        for x in range(0, blockSizeX * 4, 4):
            pixelCoord += x 
            pixelData += bmpstr[pixelCoord : pixelCoord + 3]
        pixelCoord += imgWidth * 4
    return pixelData
```

This works, but takes extremely long (almost a full second). I was hoping to get 5-10 fps for this application, and this part of the code alone is too slow. I am planning to multi-thread this code, which would somewhat mitigate the speed issues, but still this is way too slow I think. What I am looking for is a faster way to sample this bitmap so that I can get some portion of the data out, but I need to do this quickly. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution using [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html):

```
>>> def drop_alpha(s):
...     return ''.join(itertools.compress(
...             s, itertools.cycle([True, True, True, False])))
...
>>> drop_alpha('12345678')
'123567'
```

No interpreted code in the inner loop, and it's linear-time instead of quadratic, so it should be pretty fast. If you're going to be doing any image processing more complex than this, it'd be worth looking into the various [libraries](https://www.google.com/search?q=python%20image%20processing) available.

Comment: The use of two itertools functions (one of my favorite modules) is very clean - and a very good solution.  compress with cycle - +1.

Answer (score 0):

At the very least not using string concatenation will help, using:

```
pixelData = []
...
for y in range (blockSizeY * 4):
  ...
  pixelData.extend(bmpstr[pixelCoord : pixelCoord + 3])
...
return "".join(pixelData)
```

(and remove the other places that initialize and reference the old string pixelData variable)

However, this also seems like something that would be much more efficient at load time - can whatever library you're using to load the image drop the alpha channel on load (or do an internal transform which is probably implemented in C)?

Comment: I'm capturing the image (its a screenshot) using the code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589206/python-windows-7-screenshot-without-pil I'm not really familiar with the win32 API and as I was saying the goal of this project isn't to learn C. So if there is a way to get a screen shot that will work without much fiddling with C I would be interested to hear of it

Comment: If you're using PIL to get the image with ImageGrab, you can just use `img.convert("RGB")` to remove the alpha channel.

Answer (score 0):

I've no idea how fast this will be, but if you convert to an array the deletion becomes easy:

```
>>> s = "rgba"*10
>>> s
'rgbargbargbargbargbargbargbargbargbargba'
>>> import array
>>> a = array.array('c', s)
>>> a
array('c', 'rgbargbargbargbargbargbargbargbargbargba')
>>> del a[3::4]
>>> a
array('c', 'rgbrgbrgbrgbrgbrgbrgbrgbrgbrgb')
```

A better solution would be as Nick Bastin commented on one of the other answers: just use PIL for your image manipulation.