# Screenshot of external window in windows in Python

Tags: python, qt, screenshot, win32gui

I found this question : [Get screenshot on Windows with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846947/get-screenshot-on-windows-with-python)

to take a screenshot of the full desktop:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import QPixmap, QApplication
from datetime import datetime

date = datetime.now()
filename = date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.jpg')
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
QPixmap.grabWindow(QApplication.desktop().winId()).save(filename, 'jpg')
```

However, I would like to take a screenshot of an external window.
I have the hwnd of the window I want to take the screenshot off using win32gui.

Comment: i would imagine you do it the exact same way, but you'll need to extract the window ID from the `hwnd`..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation for winId](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#winId), the returned value is platform dependent.

So for Windows, it surely must (famous last words), return a `hwnd` and thus need no further conversion. If so, then try:

```
    QPixmap.grabWindow(hwnd).save(filename, 'jpg')
```

(PS: I have actually tested this now on WinXP, and it works okay for me).

Comment: Hey strangely it worked on one off my computers, but on the other its saying: TypeError: QPixmap.grabWindow(sip.voidptr, int x=0, int y=0, int width=-1, int height=-1): argument 1 has unexpected type 'lo
ng'

Comment: on that computer Im on windows 7; but I dont know whats the issue

Comment: its asking me for a sip.voidptr object

Comment: @edi9999. Well, I did say "famous last words" :) The first argument of `grabWindow` should be an `int` (see the [PyQt4 docs](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qpixmap.html#grabWindow)) - so I don't know why things would be different on Windows 7 (and I can't test things myself). What version of Qt and PyQt are you using?

Comment: I'm currently upgrading both to the latest versions (2.7.6 for python), i will comment again if it still does'nt work