# Python Screen reading and compare with image

Tags: python, image, screen

Hey I am pretty new to python, but I am looking for a possibility to compare my running application with an image and check if this image is displayed in the running application. And if yes I want to get the coords of the matching position. Is that possible?

I think its something with PIL with imagegrab or something but I am not really sure if that will work as intended.

Comment: is this for a website or a desktop application?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27343997/using-pil-python-image-library-to-detect-image-on-screen)

Comment: @AzyCrw4282 its an desktop application. Thanks for the link I will check this

Comment: Did u solve it? Let me know if u need any help

Comment: Yea I solved it thank you, it working pretty well.

Comment: I have updated the answer that solved your problem. Feel free to accept the by clicking the tick sign, for more on that see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using `PIL` and `openCV` for this job.

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
pil_img = ImageGrab.grab()
opencv_img = numpy.array(pil_img)
```

then use OpenCV to process the image to find sub-image you are looking for. See these that does what you are looking for, but even allows the image to be rotated, scaled, etc.

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/detection_of_planar_objects/detection_of_planar_objects.html

If you want to do this cross platform, then you will need to use wxWidgets to do the screengrab, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10089645/455532)