# Pyautogui: Image validation

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui

I'm using pyautogui for my project, here is a snippets of the code

```
# Other function inside while loop
 time.sleep(8)
 Click('join_audio.png')
 break
```

Click() is a class i made that locate the image and click it, but i want the action to start when that image has appeared on the screen instead of waiting for 8 second which is not that effective. Is there a way to do this in python?

Comment: You could programmatically check for the image's existence in a loop, with small sleeps in the loop. Without more background info through it's impossible to really help you.

Comment: the while loop only consist of pyautogui clicking a specific button with time.sleep() between each action. My project is internet-based, that's why i want to use image validation rather than time.sleep()

Comment: What do you mean by Image Validation in this case?

Comment: I want to detect if the image exist on the screen, in this case i want join_audio.png to exist on the screen then click it, else it wait until it the image exist.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27343997/using-pil-python-image-library-to-detect-image-on-screen) help?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `time.sleep`, you can use this code:

```
from pyautogui import *
hotkey("alt", "tab")
Click("join_audio.png")
break
```

But you have to make sure that if you press Alt-Tab, the image will be there on the screen. If you do that, then this will work for you