# Saving an output of a program in python as an image

Tags: python, python-chess

I need to save an image of a chessboard, like the one created by this code:

```
import chess
board = chess.Board()
board
```

The output is the starting chessboard:

[image: chessboard]

How can I save this image and print it (for example inside a function)? Is there a unique package for these things in python? If I try to print the board (typing `print (board)`) I get a string that presents the chessboard, not the same photo.

Comment: You can use `dir(board)` to see the available fields/methods on your chess board. Maybe there's something there to save an image or get its representation in bytes, which could then be written to disk?

Comment: check source code to see what module it uses. For most GUI frameworks you can write code which gets pixels from "canvas" in window and you can write it in file. Problem can be with `Tkinter`.

Comment: BTW: you can try to use some module to take screenshot.  ie.[pyscreenshot](https://pypi.org/project/pyscreenshot/), [PyAutoGUI](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html), [mss](https://github.com/BoboTiG/python-mss). See: [Get screenshot on Windows with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846947/get-screenshot-on-windows-with-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ***sys*** to write the output into an svg file and then save it.
First use ***chess.svg*** to create the svg file of chess board and then assign svg in some variable and write that data in the file.

```
import sys
import chess.svg
import chess
board = chess.Board()
boardsvg = chess.svg.board()
outputfile = open('name.svg', "w")
outputfile.write(boardsvg)
outputfile.close()
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: *"output into an svg/png file"* - might elaborate on this? As far as I know, the `chess` library doesn't enable an output to `.png`. The only option might be converting it afterwards, though I deem that to be pretty inefficient.

Comment: Thanks for the catch. Let me make an edit here.

Answer (score 2):

you have to write chess.svg.board(board = board) other whise you will have an empty board