# Is there any way I can get the RGB information from the desktop background?

Tags: python, background-color

I want the RGB color information of the desktop background applications with pixels as input in between certain intervals. How can I do it?

Comment: Do you mean that you have an image and you want to the RGB of the pixels inside this image?

Comment: Not image, but I want to get the color info of the desktop applications

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are on windows/macOS, you could use `PIL` or it's fork `Pillow` like this:

```py
import PIL.ImgaeGrab  # Pillow is also imported as PIL

x = y = 10
pixel = (x, y)

scrn = PIL.ImageGrab.grab()
scrn.getpixel(pixel)
>>> (246, 138, 30) # The result for me
```

For other method capturing you screen you could look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846947/get-screenshot-on-windows-with-python)

For the time interval just use `time.sleep(seconds)`