# How to take screenshot of full window with Selenium/ChromeDriver (Python)

Tags: python, windows, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, screenshot

I'm using: `driver.get_screenshot_as_file("myscreenshot.png")`, but I only get a screenshot inside the browser. I would like to take a screenshot of the full window (showing the Windows 10 taskbar, this is because I need the time to be displayed)

Thanks in advance for your help.

[Example what I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBziR.png)

Comment: You can't do that with selenium, use [`mss`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mss/). Considering that, this is a possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846947/get-screenshot-on-windows-with-python)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get screenshot on Windows with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846947/get-screenshot-on-windows-with-python)