# How can i take screenshots of a website while using python requests?

Tags: python, python-requests, webpage-screenshot

I currently scrape a website and take a screenshot when a certain case happens.
I want to consume less bandwidth so im trying to do it via Requests.
I cant figure out how will i take screenshots but i thought of a workaround which:
Once the certain case happens - it will open chrome as usual - take screenshot - close chrome.

Any smarter way im not thinking about?
Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get screenshot on Windows with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846947/get-screenshot-on-windows-with-python?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 1):

Request is a library for making HTTP requests. You can't "take a screenshot" with it, it makes no sense.

Maybe try Selenium instead.

Comment: Yes, as i thought. So I can do selenium once the date was booked with requests.