# Python# screenshot failure

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am using PIL(Python Imaging Library) for grabbing the image. But `grabber()` throws the following error message if I minimized the window

```
img=ImageGrab.grab()
File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageGrab.py", line 47, in grab
    size, data = grabber()
IOError: screen grab failed
```

My browser shot factory is installed in a Win 2003 Server in a VM. I am doing a remote desktop to view the browser shot factory's console.

Comment: You shouldn't link a (your?) porn site to your profile!

Answer (score 0):

There is a very similar question located [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69645/take-a-screenshot-via-a-python-script-linux) - it even has some alternatives and solutions, and (as Adam Bernier has written), imagegrab works only on Windows.