# Why do I only get the Desktop wallpaper when trying to take a screenshot on a Mac?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, screenshot, screen-scraping

I'm trying to take a screenshot with python. But every option I try only seems to return the desktop wallpaper and not the programs on top.

Here's a run through of what I've tried and how I'm doing it.

First I used [autopy](https://github.com/stinnux/autopy) to try and get pixels from the screen using `autopy.color.hex_to_rgb(autopy.screen.get_color(x, y))`. But it was only telling me the pixels of the desktop background.

Then I tried [PIL(Pillow)](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/) using this code:

```
from PIL import ImageGrab

im = ImageGrab.grab()
im.save('screenshot.png')
```

This only returned the desktop wallpaper.

Finally, I've tried using this script which I found on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4524723/take-screenshot-in-python-on-mac-os-x).

```
import Quartz
import LaunchServices
from Cocoa import NSURL
import Quartz.CoreGraphics as CG


def screenshot(path, region = None):
    """region should be a CGRect, something like:

    >>> import Quartz.CoreGraphics as CG
    >>> region = CG.CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)
    >>> sp = ScreenPixel()
    >>> sp.capture(region=region)

    The default region is CG.CGRectInfinite (captures the full screen)
    """

    if region is None:
        region = CG.CGRectInfinite

    # Create screenshot as CGImage
    image = CG.CGWindowListCreateImage(
        region,
        CG.kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly,
        CG.kCGNullWindowID,
        CG.kCGWindowImageDefault)

    dpi = 72 # FIXME: Should query this from somewhere, e.g for retina displays

    url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath_(path)

    dest = Quartz.CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL(
        url,
        LaunchServices.kUTTypePNG, # file type
        1, # 1 image in file
        None
        )

    properties = {
        Quartz.kCGImagePropertyDPIWidth: dpi,
        Quartz.kCGImagePropertyDPIHeight: dpi,
        }

    # Add the image to the destination, characterizing the image with
    # the properties dictionary.
    Quartz.CGImageDestinationAddImage(dest, image, properties)

    # When all the images (only 1 in this example) are added to the destination, 
    # finalize the CGImageDestination object. 
    Quartz.CGImageDestinationFinalize(dest)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Capture full screen
    screenshot("/tmp/testscreenshot_full.png")

    # Capture region (100x100 box from top-left)
    region = CG.CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)
    screenshot("/tmp/testscreenshot_partial.png", region=region)
```

Again it returns my desktop wallpaper.

Why is it doing this? How can I get a screenshot in the same way I would if I were to press 'cmd + shift + 3'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a privacy feature, macOS prevents arbitrary apps from viewing the contents of other app windows. To get permission, your app will need [access to the screen recording permission in macOS preferences](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/control-access-to-screen-recording-on-mac-mchld6aa7d23/mac).

Since this is a Python script, I think the app you're running the script from needs to be given permission, so either Terminal or whatever IDE you're using.

Comment: Excellent, this is exactly it! Thank you so much. I tried to do that first. The popup comes up every time I launch the program even when I add 'Python' and 'IDLE' to the permissions list. In the end it didn't work so I ended up clicking deny every time and didn't think it was making any difference. For some reason I can't get the permissions to work to allow it to screenshot from IDLE. I added terminal to the permissions and ran the program that way. Now it works!