# Taking screenshot from a python script by selecting the area

Tags: python, screenshot, gnome

I saw that post (that is really helpful : [Take a screenshot via a python script. [Linux]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69645/take-a-screenshot-via-a-python-script-linux)) about taking a screenshot from python. It works well but I'd like to have the same behavior as gnome-screenshot : having the possibility to choose between :

- Capturing the whole desktop
- Capturing an active window
- Capturing an area

Is there a way to do this in python, or, eventually, to use the gnome-screenshot application to do it, and then getting the file ?

I tried to find the perfect command line for gnome-screenshot to be launched without asking where to save the screenshot after by giving the path at the call, but I can't find it.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not limited to using using gnome-screenshot specifically, ImageMagick's `import` command can save directly to file without an interactive prompt.

See here for details: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/import.php

In addition to the command line interface, there is also a [Python API](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/api.php#python).

Answer (score 2):

I have a wrapper project ([pyscreenshot](https://github.com/ponty/pyscreenshot)) for scrot, imagemagick, pyqt, wx and pygtk.
If you have one of them, you can use it.
Capturing an active window is missing.

Install:

```
easy_install pyscreenshot
```

Example:

```
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab

# fullscreen
im=ImageGrab.grab()
im.show()

# part of the screen
im=ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(10,10,500,500))
im.show()

# to file
ImageGrab.grab_to_file('im.png')
```