# Creating a screenshot of a gtk.Window

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, screenshot

For testing and documentation purposes I would like to create a screenshot of a gtk.Window object. I'm following a basic pygtk sample at the moment. The example with my modifications looks like the following:

```
import gtk

def main():
    button = gtk.Button("Hello")
    scroll_win = gtk.ScrolledWindow()
    scroll_win.add(button)
    win = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
    win.add(scroll_win)
    win.show_all()

    if win.is_drawable() is not True:
        raise RuntimeError("Not drawable?")

    width, height = win.get_size()
    pixbuf = gtk.gdk.Pixbuf(gtk.gdk.COLORSPACE_RGB, False, 8,
                            width, height)
    screenshot = pixbuf.get_from_drawable(win, win.get_colormap(),
                                          0, 0, 0, 0, width, height)
    screenshot.save('screenshot.png', 'png')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    gtk.main()
```

I'm ending up with an error when the get_from_drawable method is invoked.

```
TypeError: Gdk.Pixbuf.get_from_drawable() argument 1 must be gtk.gdk.Drawable, not gtk.Window
```

Apparently [the screenshot example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69645/take-a-screenshot-via-a-python-script-linux/782768#782768) that I merged into the basic example is using a gtk.gdk.Window that inherits from gtk.gdk.Drawable.

My questions:

- Is there another way to make the Pixbuf object capture the window?
- Can I make a gtk.Window a gtk.gdk.Window or find the gtk.gdk.Window functionality within the gtk.Window?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The key difference to understand is that `gtk.gdk.Window` isn't a "window" in the sense that most people think of. It's not a GUI element, it's just a section of the screen that acts as a logical display area, as [explained in the documentation](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gdkwindow.html). In that way, it is more of a low-level object.

A `gtk.Window` object (the traditional "window") contains a `window` attribute which is the `gtk.gdk.Window` object that is used by the `gtk.Window`. It gets created when the window is initialized (in this case, after the call to `win.show_all()`).

Here's a revision of your code that saves the image correctly:

```
import gtk
import gobject

def main():
    button = gtk.Button("Hello")
    scroll_win = gtk.ScrolledWindow()
    scroll_win.add(button)
    win = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
    win.add(scroll_win)
    win.show_all()

    # Set timeout to allow time for the screen to be drawn
    # before saving the window image
    gobject.timeout_add(1000, drawWindow, win)

def drawWindow(win):
    width, height = win.get_size()
    pixbuf = gtk.gdk.Pixbuf(gtk.gdk.COLORSPACE_RGB, False, 8, width, height)

    # Retrieve the pixel data from the gdk.window attribute (win.window)
    # of the gtk.window object
    screenshot = pixbuf.get_from_drawable(win.window, win.get_colormap(), 
                                          0, 0, 0, 0, width, height)

    screenshot.save('screenshot.png', 'png')

    # Return False to stop the repeating interval
    return False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    gtk.main()
```

The timeout is necessary because even though the `gtk.gdk.Window` object has been created, the screen still hasn't been drawn, until `gtk.main()` starts running, I think. If you read the pixel buffer right after `win.show_all()`, it will save an image, but the image will be the section of the screen that the window will later take up. If you want to try it for yourself, replace the call to `gobject.timeout_add` with a simple call to `drawWindow(win)`.

Note that this method saves an image of the GTK window, but not the border of the window (so, no title bar).

Also, as a side point, when defining a function that was called using `gobject.timeout_add`, you don't actually have to use `return False` explicitly, it just has to evaluate to a value equivalent to `0`. Python return `None` by default if there is no `return` statement in the function, so the function will only be called once by default. If you want the function to be called again after another interval, return `True`.

### Using signals

As noted by liberforce, instead of using a timeout, a better method would be to connect to the signals that are used by GTK to communicate events (and state changes in general).

Anything that inherits from `gobject.GObject` (which all widgets do, basically) has a `connect()` function which is used to register a callback with a given signal. I tried out a few signals, and it appears that the one we want to use is `expose-event`, which occurs anytime a widget needs to be redrawn (including the first time it is drawn). Because we want the window to be drawn before our callback occurs, we'll use the `connect_after()` variant.

Here's the revised code:

```
import gtk

# Don't use globals in a real application,
# better to encapsulate everything in a class
handlerId = 0

def main():
    button = gtk.Button("Hello")
    scroll_win = gtk.ScrolledWindow()
    scroll_win.add(button)
    win = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
    win.add(scroll_win)

    # Connect to expose signal to allow time
    # for the window to be drawn
    global handlerId 
    handlerId = win.connect_after('expose-event', drawWindow)

    win.show_all()

def drawWindow(win, e):
    width, height = win.get_size()
    pixbuf = gtk.gdk.Pixbuf(gtk.gdk.COLORSPACE_RGB, False, 8, width, height)

    # Retrieve the pixel data from the gdk.window attribute (win.window)
    # of the gtk.window object
    screenshot = pixbuf.get_from_drawable(win.window, win.get_colormap(), 
                                          0, 0, 0, 0, width, height)
    screenshot.save('screenshot.png', 'png')

    # Disconnect this handler so that it isn't
    # repeated when the screen needs to be redrawn again
    global handlerId
    win.disconnect(handlerId)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    gtk.main()
```

Comment: Great answer. You explained it in a detail that went above and beyond what I asked for; and you threw in some other useful bits. Thank you!

Comment: The timeout should be replaced IMHO by the connection to a signal that happens when we're sure that the gtk.gdk.Window has been created. Maybe `realize` or `map-event`, or something like that.

Comment: @liberforce: Yes, that is a good point. I've updated the answer to include some more information on signals. Thanks!

Comment: @voithos: I used your code, but it doesn't work for alpha channels. Please see my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899756/how-to-get-a-png-alpha-channel-screenshot-of-gtk-window

Comment: Note that you don't need a global variable - simply pass the `handlerId` to the callback using a lambda to obtain late binding. E.g.: `handlerId = win.connect_after('expose-event', drawWindow, lambda: handlerId)`. The `drawWindow` then gets an additional `getId` argument, and ends with `win.disconnect(getId())`. This avoids global vars without requiring a whole dedicated class.

Comment: Note: In PyGtk 3, this event is now called `draw`, not `expose-event`.