# How to get RGB values of QPixmap or QImage pixel - Qt, PyQt

Tags: python, linux, image, pyqt, pyqt4

Based on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/769221/544721 , I've made following code printing values in grabbed region:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import QPixmap, QApplication
app = QApplication(sys.argv)

# img is QImage type
img = QPixmap.grabWindow(
        QApplication.desktop().winId(),
        x=00,
        y=100,
        height=20,
        width=20,
        ).toImage()

for x in range(0,20):
    for y in range(0,20):
        print( "({},{}) = {}".format( x,y,(img.pixel(x,y)) ) )
```

But pixels are displayed like this:

```
(0,0) = 4285163107
(0,1) = 4285163107
(0,2) = 4285163107
(0,3) = 4285163107
(0,4) = 4285163107
(0,5) = 4285163107
```

How to get RGB values of `QImage` (obtained from `QPixmap`) pixels ? (preferably, solution working in 16,24,32 screen bit depths) ?

Example output:

```
(0,0) = (0,0,0)
...
(10,15) = (127,15,256)
```

(Solution for Linux, written in Python3)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The issue you are seeing is that the number being returned from img.pixel() is actually a QRgb value that is a format independent value. You can then convert it into the proper representation as such:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import QPixmap, QApplication, QColor
app = QApplication(sys.argv)

# img is QImage type
img = QPixmap.grabWindow(
        QApplication.desktop().winId(),
        x=00,
        y=100,
        height=20,
        width=20,
        ).toImage()

for x in range(0,20):
    for y in range(0,20):
        c = img.pixel(x,y)
        colors = QColor(c).getRgbF()
        print "(%s,%s) = %s" % (x, y, colors)
```

#### Output

```
(0,0) = (0.60784313725490191, 0.6588235294117647, 0.70980392156862748, 1.0)
(0,1) = (0.60784313725490191, 0.6588235294117647, 0.70980392156862748, 1.0)
(0,2) = (0.61176470588235299, 0.6588235294117647, 0.71372549019607845, 1.0)
(0,3) = (0.61176470588235299, 0.66274509803921566, 0.71372549019607845, 1.0)
```

[QImage docs](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qimage.html):

> The color of a pixel can be retrieved by passing its coordinates to
>   the pixel() function. The pixel() function returns the color as a QRgb
>   value indepedent of the image's format.

Answer (score 4):

The color components of the `QRgb` value returned by `QImage.pixel` can either be extracted directly, or via a `QColor` object:

```
>>> from PyQt4 import QtGui
>>> rgb = 4285163107
>>> QtGui.qRed(rgb), QtGui.qGreen(rgb), QtGui.qBlue(rgb)
(106, 102, 99)
>>> QtGui.QColor(rgb).getRgb()[:-1]
(106, 102, 99)
```