# Capturing screenshots with Python in Windows and Linux

Tags: python, image

Is there any python library which can get print screenshot on both linux and windows? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: -1 for what exactly? This baffles me a lot!

Comment: most likely for not searching google and/or stack overflow.   in less than 5 seconds I found this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69645/take-a-screenshot-via-a-python-script-linux  and that is just one of many

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library [Castro](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/castro/1.0.4) can be used for your cause.

Here is a sample code from the documentation

```
from castro import Castro
c = Castro()
c.start()
# Do something awesome!
c.stop()
```

Comment: I looked in Castro and it is nice due to its simplicity! thanks. I don't want to use gtk though because I wonder how it will work on windows ( I am scared by its not-native nature to other platform than linux for GUI. I use wxpython for GUI)

Answer (score 0):

I have googled a bit and saw this on a forumn.

```
import gtk.gdk

w = gtk.gdk.get_default_root_window()
sz = w.get_size()
print "The size of the window is %d x %d" % sz
pb = gtk.gdk.Pixbuf(gtk.gdk.COLORSPACE_RGB,False,8,sz[0],sz[1])
pb = pb.get_from_drawable(w,w.get_colormap(),0,0,0,0,sz[0],sz[1])
if (pb != None):
    pb.save("screenshot.png","png")
    print "Screenshot saved to screenshot.png."
else:
    print "Unable to get the screenshot."
```

The link to the stackoverflow answer is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69645/take-a-screenshot-via-a-python-script-linux)