# Create field to accept mouse drawings and convert it to an image

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, ocr, tkinter-canvas

I want to create a field in python that will accept mouse drawings and convert it into 28x28 pixels image:

[image: field like this]

I want to use this image result to predict the output using a model that i have already trained, the model is of hand writing recognition where each image is of 28x28 pixels

Comment: This looks like a good start... https://stackoverflow.com/a/40617081/2836621

Comment: Thank you so much sir, that helps a lot

Comment: Excellent! Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Tkinter` along with `PIL` (Python Imaging Library) to perform your task.

I came across [THIS QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17915440/python-tkinter-save-canvas-as-image-using-pil) which solves the problem of saving drawings on a canvas as an image.

I modified the existing code to resize the image to dimension of 28 x 28 and saved the result.

Follow the code in the link and in the `save()` just the `resize()` function before saving the image:

```
def save(self):
    filename = "C:/Users/Desktop/my_drawing.jpg"
    self.image = self.image.resize((28, 28), 1)
    self.image.save(filename)
```

Comment: @MarkSetchell It took me some time and I didn't know I had Tkinter built-in. It was really exciting to try out something new!

Comment: The result that I am getting is not quite good, I have read about html canvas tag but for that i have to make an entire page, so how can i make it good

Comment: I am getting error while reshaping in my Neural Network

Comment: @HrishikeshVichore Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Sorry, the problem has been sorted, it was because of my mistake

Comment: Okay sure , I will do that