# How can I convert tkinter application into image?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

For example I have a simple tkinter application with some labels and arrows(or common lines). My application can visualise (f.e) a family tree, but I have to get an image of that to send it for a some reason. Of course, I can make a screenshot of it and send to anyone I want, but it's not about python. Is there any option to convert my app into (or get) an image of my application by using tkinter (or turtle module)? I mean, photoshop or paint or other gr. editor has a "working field" where you're drawing and after that you can get an image of your "working field". How can I get an image of my tkinter app's "working field"?

Comment: There is the opportunity for a canvas (working field?) and there are several [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10432892) to this topic on SO.

Comment: ...or this? [Python Tkinter save canvas as image using PIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17915440/python-tkinter-save-canvas-as-image-using-pil)