# Convert images drawn by turtle to PNG in Python

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm making a abstract art template generator in Python that takes inputs of minimum radius, maximum radius, and number of circles. It draws random circles in random places, also meeting the user's specifications. I want to convert the Turtle graphics into a PNG so that the user can then edit the template however he/she wants to, but I don't know how to proceed. Here's my code:

```
import random  
import time  
import turtle  

print("Abstract Art Template Generator")
print()
print("This program will generate randomly placed and sized circles on a blank screen.")
num = int(input("Please specify how many circles you would like to be drawn: "))
radiusMin = int(input("Please specify the minimum radius you would like to have: "))
radiusMax = int(input("Please specify the maximum radius you would like to have: "))
screenholder = input("Press ENTER when you are ready to see your circles drawn: ")

t = turtle.Pen()

win = turtle.Screen()


def mycircle():
    x = random.randint(radiusMin,radiusMax) 
    t.circle(x)

    t.up()
    y = random.randint(0,360)
    t.seth(y)
    if t.xcor() < -300 or t.xcor() > 300:
        t.goto(0, 0)
    elif t.ycor() < -300 or t.ycor() > 300:
        t.goto(0, 0)
    z = random.randint(0,100)
    t.forward(z)
    t.down()


for i in range(0, num):
    mycircle()


turtle.done()
```

Comment: I'm not a god of python but maybe theese code samples could help : http://code.activestate.com/recipes/580495-random-planet-generator-using-plasma-fractal/?in=lang-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting from a postscript file (*.ps) to a PNG can be done with ghostscript.  This open-source program is available on multiple platforms.
Another option is ImageMagick, also open source and multi platform.

Just search on the internet for "convert ps to PNG ghostscript" or "convert ps to PNG Imagemagick".

If you want to automate the conversion, have a look at the `subprocess` module (python documentation) to call the program from within your python program.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `turtle.getcanvas()` to generate Tkinker canvas. Then save it as postscript file.

```
...
cv = turtle.getcanvas()
cv.postscript(file="file_name.ps", colormode='color')

turtle.done()
```

Then you can convert it to png (I think you will find how to do it). Or use PIL with Tkinker - more about this method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886274/how-can-i-convert-canvas-content-to-an-image)