# How can I use Python's turtle to draw a bmp image?

Tags: python, image, turtle-graphics, bmp

I know that Python's turtle can draw pictures, and there are some examples to save the image to an eps file. But I want to save the image to a bmp (bitmap) file. Which library should I use? How can I use it? I find this question on the Internet but there is no answer now. I would appreciate it if you can help me!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35629520/convert-images-drawn-by-turtle-to-png-in-python this thread might help you