# How to send print job to printer in python

Tags: python, windows, printers, network-printers

I used Tkinter to draw some lines in python and I would like to print that picture to usb connected and/or network printer in Windows.
How should I do that?

Comment: Depends on your system. Are you on windows or another?

Comment: thanks for pointing it out. it's Windows

Comment: You need to first convert your graphics into an image file and then print that. Windows can print .bmp files natively, so that might be a good image file type to create. To get started see [_How can I convert canvas content to an image?_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886274/how-can-i-convert-canvas-content-to-an-image)

Comment: Tim Golden has a good [_How do I print?_](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/print.html) Python Stuff article that's Window specific.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this! It uses os module to start the file in the default printer!

```
import os

os.startfile("YourDocument", "print")
```

Comment: This definitely works. but am curious is there a way to print the file without having to open it first