# How to turn turtle graphic output into an image file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I have been trying to figure out how to output a Python turtle graphic as an image. I have checked multiple threads and still cannot quite figure it out (i've tried to make a postscript file and convert it but no luck and also tried to put the turtle onto a tkinter canvas and then save but no luck). I have installed pillow but still cannot convert the output. Below I have added a basic turtle graphic which if someone could show how to code it to make an image file (JPG or PNG) I would be grateful and explanation of what they did. I'm using Python 3.7.1 and Windows.

```
import turtle 

polygon = turtle.Turtle()

num_sides = 6
side_length = 70
angle = 360.0 / num_sides 

for i in range(num_sides):
    polygon.forward(side_length)
    polygon.right(angle)

turtle.done()
```

Answer (score 1):

Adapting [How can I convert canvas content to an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10432892/6243352) to turtle, you can use:

```py
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

Screen().tracer(0)
polygon = Turtle()

num_sides = 6
side_length = 70
angle = 360.0 / num_sides 

for i in range(num_sides):
    polygon.forward(side_length)
    polygon.right(angle)

Screen().update()
Screen().getcanvas().postscript(file="out.eps")
```

Disabling tracer and using update is optional, but speeds up the process, although the window will still open momentarily. See [Is it possible to use turtle without the graphics window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71941523/is-it-possible-to-use-turtle-without-the-graphics-window) if interested.

[An answer from the thread linked at the top of this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10432892/6243352) has code to convert the eps to a jpg. An approach with PIL can work, like the one in [how to convert eps to jpg or png using python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73234913/how-to-convert-eps-to-jpg-or-png-using-python-script).

Answer (score 0):

To save to a file, you can use postscript.

```
from turtle import *
import turtle

polygon = turtle.Turtle()

num_sides = 6
side_length = 70
angle = 360.0 / num_sides 

for i in range(num_sides):
    polygon.forward(side_length)
    polygon.right(angle)

ts = turtle.getscreen()
ts.getcanvas().postscript(file="polygon.eps")

turtle.done()
```

Your canvas (from `Tkinter`) is what has a postscript function, so you must use `.getcanvas()` to use postscript.