# Is it possible to use turtle without the graphics window?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am working on a simulation which requires geometric computations.
`turtle` library makes my life much easier because of the convenient functions that I can use such as `towards()`, `setheading()`, `goto()`, etc.

However, I do not need to see the drawing. Is there a way to turn off the graphics window? I only want to output the results of the simulations in a text file.

Comment: Is it the `turtle.TNavigator` that you're after?

Comment: @StevenSummers Could be, I really don't know.

Comment: It should be fairly simply to implement something like that from scratch.

Comment: You will need to be more specific re "output results of simulations to a file." What format did you have in mind? There's little doubt that the only way to do what you need is re-implement the library. The interface is not small. Though not hard, handling all possible calls won't be a small project.

Comment: @Gene I am working on a project where some billiard balls bounce around a not necessarily convex billiard table. `towards()`, `setheading()` `rotate()` functions come in very handy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, through my own experience and reading those of others, there isn't a simple in-built method in the Turtle module to hide the window or prevent the window from being instantiated.

However, there is a way to hide it by directly using [`tkinter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#), the underlying package that creates the graphics window for `turtle`, and the `RawTurtle` class (credit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7237125/7386092)).

1. Instantiate a `Tk` object to serve as the main window
2. Call the `withdraw()` method (alias for the `wm_withdraw()` method) on it (this hides the window)
3. Instantiate a `tkinter.Canvas` instance using the `Tk` object we created as its master window
4. Pass the `Canvas` instance to a `RawTurtle` instance.

```py
import tkinter
import turtle

main = tkinter.Tk()
main.withdraw()
canv = tkinter.Canvas(master = main)
turt = turtle.RawTurtle(canv)

# <insert rest of code here utilizing the RawTurtle instance>
```

[`RawTurtle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html)'s constructor takes the `Canvas` instance as the environment in which the turtle draws. By doing this, we hide the window that is typically automatically constructed and passed to the `Turtle` object (the `Turtle` class that is typically used is actually a subclass of the `RawTurtle` class that doesn't require an inputted `Canvas` instance to be constructed)

Something to remember with this solution is that the graphics system is still initiated despite the window being hidden; if you wanted to eliminate the initialization of the graphics system and window entirely, you would have to reimplement `TurtleScreenBase` to eliminate any calls to the `Tk` instance used by the turtle. At that point, I would recommend looking at extending or reimplementing many of the `turtle` methods/functions to better fit the needs of your project.

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to do this with Python Turtle but NetLogo can be run headless. Since it can be run from the command line it could be launched from a Python script.

From the [NetLogo](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/) documentation:

> NetLogo is a programmable modeling environment for simulating natural and social phenomena. [...] Headless mode allows doing batch runs from the command line [...] Command line operation is also supported.