# how to convert eps to jpg or png using python script

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('image.eps')
rgb_img = img.convert('RGB')
rgb_img.save('image.jpg')
```

I tried this code to convert my EPS image to JPG image, but I receive the error like this.
`1. "OSError: Unable to locate Ghostscript on paths"`

I executed this code in Google colab, I get the error like this.
`2. "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gs'"`

Comment: You need to install the ghostscript libraries via `pip install ghostscript`. Python needs them to convert Postscript to/from other formats.  See also https://pypi.org/project/ghostscript/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Here is my code to convert eps image to jpg or png (images)

```
from PIL import Image
eps_image = Image.open("eps_image_path")
eps_image.load(scale=10)
eps_image.save("save_path_image")
```