# Canvas not getting captured while saving tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, ghostscript

[SOLVED]
Please don't judge the code. I just need to fix one bug with capturing canvas into file.
As you can see I've tried multiple solutions and still while saving file is all-white...

Do you have any soulutions to that?

This app is to generate randomly dots on canvas with option to save it.
it works when number of dots is above 40000 and rectangle is black.
But otherwise is white.

[image]

```
HEIGTH = 207
WIDTH = 207




def snapsaveCanvas():
    fname = filename.get()
    my_window.update_idletasks()
    my_window.update()
    canvas.update()
    canvas.update_idletasks()
    ps = canvas.postscript(colormode='color')
    img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(ps.encode('utf-8')))
    img.save(fname + ".bmp", 'bmp')
    print("done")





canvas = tk.Canvas(frame2, width=HEIGTH, height=WIDTH, background='white')
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0)
canvas.create_rectangle(4, 4, 206, 206)
```

Comment: Why don't you just show the code and the traceback?

Comment: I wanted to put it into comment as I was prevented from putting it in the post...

Comment: sorry i could not save without this string below

Comment: Whats the error? Could you include some picture?

Comment: @CoolCloud added. The issue is that when i want to save results i see blank image unless i put more then 40000 dots to make canvas full black.

It should looks like on the canvas when i add 25000 but its white after saving. black1 file.

Comment: What does `img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(ps.encode('utf-8')))` ? as an alternative you could also get the window location and get the screenshot of the window.

Comment: it encode canvas poscript and coverts it to bmp , I tried to use PIL.grabImage but it is not a good solution.. Its better to use scrapping tool  but its not what i want.

Comment: or if i can get window location and then capture canvas area within that app window that would be enough but I dont know how to do this.

Comment: several methods you can try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886274/how-can-i-convert-canvas-content-to-an-image

Comment: Thanks Wups. it helps.. there were one method I was not aware of :)

Comment: Is this issue solved?

Comment: yes, its working fine now . I've posted answer below.

Thanks for paying attention and being helpful :) It took me 2h to try diffrent solutions and I was so desparate to post this issue  : D

Answer (score 1):

Ok, thanks for links.

I've tested several methods and one of them works.
taken from [How can I convert canvas content to an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886274/how-can-i-convert-canvas-content-to-an-image)

```
import win32gui

def snapsaveCanvas():
    fileName = filename.get()
    canvas.update()
    canvas.update_idletasks()

    HWND = canvas.winfo_id()  # get the handle of the canvas
    rect = win32gui.GetWindowRect(HWND)  # get the coordinate of the canvas
    im = ImageGrab.grab(rect).save(fileName + ".bmp")
    print("done")
```

Comment: I prefer using `pygetwindow` instead of `win32gui`, isnt it an overkill?