# How can I save an animation created with tkinter's gui and canvas?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a working animation, but I'm wondering how to save the animation after it displays once.

```
gui = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(gui, width=800,height=600,bg='white')
(objects/shapes created here)
for i in range(num_frames):
     canvas.move(blah blah)
     gui.update()
     time.sleep(.01)

gui.mainloop()
```

Comment: Save it for what purpose? Save it as an animated gif? A movie? A python script?

Comment: You can create animated gif files using the [Pillow fork of the PIL](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/). You will need to save the canvas multiple times to create a series of frames comprising the result.

Comment: Also see [How can I convert canvas content to an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886274/how-can-i-convert-canvas-content-to-an-image)