# 'Exporting' a tkinter canvas to .png with Pillow and results in extremely low resolution

Tags: tkinter, python-imaging-library, png, ghostscript, tkinter-canvas

I'm trying to 'export' a `tkinter` canvas to a `png` file, as in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55385764/15862653

I created a sample canvas and a button that triggers a function to export it to png:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image

def save_as_png(canvas, fileName):
    canvas.postscript(file='./' + fileName + '.eps', colormode='color')
    img = Image.open(fileName + '.eps')
    img.convert()
    img.save(fileName + '.png', 'png')


root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=100, height=100)
text = canvas.create_text(50, 50, anchor='center', text='Some text')
button = tk.Button(root, text='Save canvas', command=lambda: save_as_png(canvas, 'my canvas'))
canvas.pack()
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

The image that results has extremely low resolution, though. I took me a while even to understand that 'Some text' is actually what is written:

[image]

I tried fiddling with the arguments (`dpi`, `quality`, `compression_level`) of both the `open` and the `save` methods, with no luck.

Comment: Try setting either the `pagewidth` or `pageheight` option of `.postscript(...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the tkdoc on [`pagewidth` or `pageheight`](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/canvas.htm#M69) of `.postscript()`:

> Specifies that the Postscript should be scaled in both x and y so that the printed area is size high on the Postscript page. Size consists of a floating-point number followed by c for centimeters, i for inches, m for millimeters, or p or nothing for printer's points (1/72 inch). Defaults to the height of the printed area on the screen. If both -pageheight and -pagewidth are specified then the scale factor from -pagewidth is used (non-uniform scaling is not implemented).

```py
# set the output width to 1000 pixels
canvas.postscript(file='./'+fileName+'.eps', colormode='color', pagewidth=1000)
```

Comment: Thanks! If they defaults to the printed area on the screen, why don't I get the same resolution I see on the canvas without setting those arguments?