# How to turn a tkinter canvas circle shape into an image

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

image 1:

[image]

image 2:

[image]

I want to turn a tkinter canvas shape into an image. How do I do it?

Python Code

```
class Bricks:
    def __init__(self, canvas, color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.id = canvas.create_oval(5, 5, 25, 25, fill=color, width=2)
```

Source
[enter link description here](https://codingshiksha.com/python/python-3-tkinter-script-to-build-a-bubble-shooter-game-gui-desktop-app-full-project-for-beginners/)

Answer (score 1):

See [that thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886274/how-can-i-convert-canvas-content-to-an-image) to **save** an image from the canvas. Just make a smaller canvas, draw jour circle and save it.

```py
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageGrab

def getter(widget):
    x=root.winfo_rootx()+widget.winfo_x()
    y=root.winfo_rooty()+widget.winfo_y()
    x1=x+widget.winfo_width()
    y1=y+widget.winfo_height()
    ImageGrab.grab().crop((x,y,x1,y1)).save("file path here")

root = Tk()
cv = Canvas(root)
cv.create_rectangle(10,10,50,50)
cv.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

See [PhotoImage](https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-photoimage/) to **load** an image from a file.

```py
from tkinter import PhotoImage

PhotoImage(file="path to image file")
```

Use `canvas.create_image(x_pos, y_pos, image=some photoimage)` to **draw** it.

```py
from tkinter import PhotoImage

image = PhotoImage(file="path to image file")

root = Tk()
cv = Canvas(root)
cv.create_image(10,10, image=image)
cv.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What I want is to replace it with a png file.

Comment: i.e. i want to put covid image there.

Comment: see [PhotoImage](https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-photoimage/) and then `canvas.create_image(x, y, image=img)`