# How can I save what I did on my canvas widget as an image?

Tags: python, image, tkinter, canvas

I've seen some questions on this topic regarding people drawing on the canvas and saving it as an image, however my problem is different:
I want to create a watermark desktop app where I can upload an image to my canvas, I add a watermark to it with the .create_text() method  and after that I want to save that result (the original image with the watermark) as a new image.
My app is already able to upload the image and add the watermark.
I wanted to know if there is a simple way to just save the canvas as an image.
I tried also to do it another way by trying to screenshot the canvas, however altough I created a screenshot function is able to do a screenshot but it ignores my canvas widget it simply screenshots what's behind it (my desktop or any other thing I have opened)...

I'll leave my current code below:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageGrab

FONT_NAME = "Courier"


def screenshot():

    full_file_name = input("Save as: ")
    x = canvas.winfo_rootx() + canvas.winfo_x()
    y = canvas.winfo_rooty() + canvas.winfo_y()
    x1 = x + canvas.winfo_reqwidth()
    y1 = y + canvas.winfo_reqheight()
    ImageGrab.grab().crop((x, y, x1, y1)).save(full_file_name)


window = Tk()
window.title("Watermark Creator")

image = input("Write the name of the image file you want to edit (don't forget to include .filetype): ")
img_width = int(input("Indicate the width of the picture to edit: "))
img_height = int(input("Indicate the height of the picture to edit: "))
watermark_text = "© " + input("What do you want written as your watermark?: ")


canvas = Canvas(width = img_width, height=img_height, highlightthickness=0) 
image_to_edit = PhotoImage(file=image)
canvas.create_image((img_width/2), (img_height/2), image = image_to_edit)
canvas.create_text((img_width/2), img_height-20, text=watermark_text, font = (FONT_NAME, 15, "italic"))
canvas.grid(column = 1, row = 1)

screenshot()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: _"...using the label widget I add a watermark to it..."_ - why are you using a label widget? Why not write the text directly on the canvas? Though, your code shows exactly that - writing the text on the canvas rather than using a label widget. Can you clarify?

Comment: My mistake, at first I tried it with the label but then I edited it to use the .create_text() to add the text on the canvas, just as it is in the code! I will edit that part on the original post!
Thank you

Comment: have a look into this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55385764/22326950) or the others in this thread. Maby one of the solutions there will help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I convert canvas content to an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886274/how-can-i-convert-canvas-content-to-an-image)

Comment: @Jan_B I tried using that as a solution, creating a postscript and converting it into a png:
def save_as_png(canvas,fileName):
    # save postscipt image 
    canvas.postscript(file = fileName + '.ps') 
    # use PIL to convert to PNG 
    img = Image.open(fileName + '.ps') 
    img.save(fileName + '.png', 'png') 

but it simply creates a png with a tiny white rectangle..