# How can i import gtk.gdk from gi.repository

Tags: python, import, pygtk, gdk

I have this python code that takes screenshot of x screen.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import gtk.gdk

w = gtk.gdk.get_default_root_window()
sz = w.get_size()
print "The size of the window is %d x %d" % sz
pb = gtk.gdk.Pixbuf(gtk.gdk.COLORSPACE_RGB,False,8,sz[0],sz[1])
pb = pb.get_from_drawable(w,w.get_colormap(),0,0,0,0,sz[0],sz[1])
if (pb != None):
    pb.save("screenshot.png","png")
    print "Screenshot saved to screenshot.png."
else:
    print "Unable to get the screenshot."
```

It works but i need to import `from gi.repository import Gdk` instead  gtk.gdk.
I have tried the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, GdkPixbuf
from gi.repository.GdkPixbuf import Pixbuf

w = Gdk.get_default_root_window()
sz = w.get_size()
print "The size of the window is %d x %d" % sz
pb = Pixbuf(Gdk.COLORSPACE_RGB,False,8,sz[0],sz[1])
pb = pb.get_from_drawable(w,w.get_colormap(),0,0,0,0,sz[0],sz[1])
if (pb != None):
    pb.save("screenshot.png","png")
    print "Screenshot saved to screenshot.png."
else:
    print "Unable to get the screenshot."
```

But:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./dsd", line 6, in <module>
    sz = w.get_size()
AttributeError: 'gtk.gdk.X11Window' object has no attribute 'get_size'
```

Is there a way to use completely gi.repository for this script?
Thanks

EDIT: I solved the problem of AttributeError: 'gtk.gdk.X11Window' object has no attribute 'get_size' using sz = w.get_geometry() instead get_size. New code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, GdkPixbuf 
from gi.repository.GdkPixbuf import Pixbuf

w = Gdk.get_default_root_window()
sz = w.get_geometry()
#print "The size of the window is %d x %d" % sz
pb = GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new(GdkPixbuf.Colorspace.RGB,False,8,sz[2],sz[3])
pb = pb.get_from_drawable(w,w.get_colormap(),0,0,0,0,sz[2],sz[3])
if (pb != None):
    pb.save("screenshot.png","png")
    print "Screenshot saved to screenshot.png."
else:
    print "Unable to get the screenshot."
```

But also having another problem with this code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./dsd", line 9, in <module>
    pb = pb.get_from_drawable(w,w.get_colormap(),0,0,0,0,sz[2],sz[3])
AttributeError: 'Pixbuf' object has no attribute 'get_from_drawable'
```

How can i use "get_from_drawable" attribute of Pixbuf?
Thanks again!

Comment: did you get any solution for AttributeError: 'Pixbuf' object has no attribute 'get_from_drawable'

Comment: @SubodhGhulaxe Unfortunately no. `dir(Pixbuf)` doesnt have any option about drawable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know that this answer arrives a bit late, but better late than never.

**Gdk3+** actually simplified the process of retrieving the `Pixbuf` from a `GdkWindow`. Thus, your code should be as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from gi.repository import Gdk, GdkPixbuf

w = Gdk.get_default_root_window()
sz = w.get_geometry()[2:4]
#print "The size of the window is %d x %d" % sz
pb = Gdk.pixbuf_get_from_window(w, 0, 0, sz[0], sz[1])
if (pb != None):
    pb.savev("screenshot.png","png", [], [])
    print "Screenshot saved to screenshot.png."
else:
    print "Unable to get the screenshot."
```

Comment: For modern Python3, I had to close up the print statements and include gi.require_version('Gdk', '3.0'). Works great! :)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you want **get_width()** and **get_height()**.

According to their docs **get_size()** is deprecated: https://developer.gnome.org/gdk/stable/gdk-Drawing-Primitives.html#gdk-drawable-get-size

Comment: Thanks @TingPing I solved the problem of get_size() using the sz = w.get_geometry()