# PyGTK+3 (PyGObject) to create screenshot?

Tags: python, linux, pygtk, pygobject

I've spend past 3 days searching in google, how can I create a screenshot with PyGTK+3 ?
There are gallizion tutorials about pyqt,pygtk+2,wx and PIL.

By the way, I don't need external programs like scrot, imlib2, imagemagick and so on.

Comment: There is not such thing as PyGtk+3. I suppose you mean PyGObject. If you add a link to the PyGtk tutorial I can translate it for you to PyGObject, which is pretty straightforward must of the time.

Comment: The first answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69645/take-a-screenshot-via-a-python-script-linux

Answer (score 7):

Since nobody else posted the translation to GTK3, here you go:

```
from gi.repository import Gdk

win = Gdk.get_default_root_window()
h = win.get_height()
w = win.get_width()

print ("The size of the window is %d x %d" % (w, h))

pb = Gdk.pixbuf_get_from_window(win, 0, 0, w, h)

if (pb != None):
    pb.savev("screenshot.png","png", (), ())
    print("Screenshot saved to screenshot.png.")
else:
    print("Unable to get the screenshot.")
```

Comment: How can you modify this code so it takes a screenshot of the entire screen?

Answer (score 3):

Better later than never. I got stuck with get_from_drawable() but later found the documentation about its deprecation.

```
from gi.repository import Gdk

window = Gdk.get_default_root_window()
x, y, width, height = window.get_geometry()

print("The size of the root window is {} x {}".format(width, height))

# get_from_drawable() was deprecated. See:
# https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/ch24s02.html#id-1.6.3.4.7
pb = Gdk.pixbuf_get_from_window(window, x, y, width, height)

if pb:
    pb.savev("screenshot.png", "png", (), ())
    print("Screenshot saved to screenshot.png.")
else:
    print("Unable to get the screenshot.")
```

Comment: It's me HexSFd, stackoverflow blocked my previous account for asking "low quality questions" and wasn't able to respond to your post. Thank you Havok, wish you all the best.

Comment: How can you modify this code so it takes a screenshot of the full screen?