# migrating from python-gtk2 to python-gi

Tags: python, migration, gtk, gtk3, gtk2

I have some python2 code that I'im migrating to python3 as python2 will reach EOL soon. And in so doing I'm also migrating from gtk2 to gtk3 via GIR. However, I am unable to find any proper documentation on how to do so.

I have the following snippets in my code that I'd like to change:

```
pixbuf = gtk.gdk.Pixbuf(gtk.gdk.COLORSPACE_RGB,False,8,width,height)
```

```
pixbuf.get_from_drawable(
gtk.gdk.get_default_root_window(),
gtk.gdk.colormap_get_system(),
0,0,0,0,
width,height)
```

```
pixbuf.save(...)
```

```
gtk.gdk.screen_width()
```

```
gtk.gdk.screen_width()
```

I came across https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/ and https://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/class-gdkpixbuf.html, but I'm kinda new to python and GTK and am not able to figure out the equivalent transformations

Any references to documentation would help too.

Answer (score 0):

You will find the replacement class for GdkPixbuf here:

- https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#GdkPixbuf-2.0/classes/Pixbuf.html

For the changes from GTK+ 2 to GTK+ 3, they are mostly documented in the C documentation, unless I overlooked something.

- https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-migrating-2-to-3.html

You'll find a tutorial on GTK+ 3 with python here:

- https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
  https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: sifting through all that definitely wasn't easy. But I managed to get it done once I realized The code snippets I used were basically taking a screenshot. Found that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20816280/pygtk3-pygobject-to-create-screenshot. Thanks anyway

Comment: Sorry, I thought that you knew you were taking a screenshot. That's basically what getting the root window and saving the pixels in it is.

Comment: This isn't my code and I just needed to do the migration. But thanks for the references @liberforce. I will need it now.